# How can I use jQuery to change CSS that defines H2?

Tags: jquery

I want to let the user tell me how h2 should style text.  I know that

```
 $('h2').css({'color':'red'});
```

will go through and change all the h2 tags to

```
<h2 style="color: red;">This is the header</h2>
```

But that doesn't change what a basic

```
 <h2>something</h2>
```

looks like.  If I tell an RTE, for example,  to put h2 tags around something, I won't get the red style that jQuery defined (most likely).

Is there a way that jQuery can change the CSS that defines the basic h2, so that the h2 set in by an RTE reflects the new style?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720332/how-to-change-the-inline-style-of-the-page-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using jQuery

You have to create a `style` element and append it to `head`, like this:

```
// array containing our styles
var styles = [
    "h2 { color: red; }",
    "h3 { color: green; }"
];

// create the style element and concat the styles
$("<style>" + styles.join("") + "</style>").appendTo("head");
```

*Note: You don't have to use the array, I only added it to make it easier to add multiple styles.*

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hA6My/).

### Using the native [CSSStyleSheet.insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)

You can also insert your rules into the stylesheet with the native `.insertRule` method:

```
// get the last stylesheet
var sheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1];

// get a reference to the insertRule function
// the addRule method is used in IE8 and older
var insertRule = sheet[sheet.insertRule ? "insertRule" : "addRule"];

// reuse the styles-array from the jQuery snippet
while (styles.length) {
    insertRule.call(sheet, styles.splice(0,1));
}
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hA6My/1/).

Comment: Thanks!  The jQuery method seems easiest and I feel more at home with jQuery.  Plus your jsfiddle for the insertRule wasn't showing the colors.  I was also directed to the jQuery.rules plugin by an earlier post.  Do you have any thoughts on that for a solution?

Comment: @Steve The native method should be preferred though but it's weird it does't work for you. What browser are you using? jQuery.rule is just a plugin that more or less does the same as the snippet in my answer. You can use it if you want, but I think it's unnecessary.

Comment: Marcus,  Your http://jsfiddle.net/hA6My/1/ jsfiddle is colorless her on Firefox and IE, but works on Chrome and Safari.  No matter.  I'm happy with the jQuery solution, which works everywhere.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM Level 2 interfaces

```
sheet.insertRule("h2 {color: red;}", 0);
```

and for IE:

```
sheet.addRule("h2","color: red;", 0);
```