# Change css properties

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to change css properties within one line of code ? Here is what I do if I want to change two properties.

```
document.getElementById('el').style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById('el').style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
```

Answer (score 7):

Move that styles to some class, and use class name instead of applying styles separately. This is recommended aproach.

```
/*CSS*/
.yourClass {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #000
}

//JS
document.getElementById('el').className = 'yourClass';
```

**EDIT**

Guys, please - stop writing jQuery examples. That is so simple task, that don't need at least 30KB library.

Comment: He probably wants to change 'some style properties' of an element. In that case a complete class change is a bit too much.

Comment: You can always add a second class name instead of changing exsisting one. Using class instead of styles it's recommended practice, because it has better performance, and it's easier in implementation, especially, when you add additional properties. And, in class solution you don't have remember parameters before change, you only need to remove added class name from element.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('el').cssText = "display:inline; background-color:#000000";
```

Comment: Wouldn't this overwrite all other inline CSS?

Comment: yes but that would be the only way to do it in 1 line, without using any framework

Answer (score 2):

you can try to change the class of the element using jqueryf for example :

```
$("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
```

or  use the attr method :

```
$("p").attr("class" yourClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it liket his if you are using jQuery:

```
$("#el").css({ display : "inline", "backgroundColor" : "#000000" });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the CSS values as string and there is no other CSS already set for the element (or you don't care about overwriting), make us of the **cssText** property:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").style.cssText = cssString;
```

Check SO link for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968772/287100

Answer (score 0):

Without any frameworks, there really isn't an acceptable solution. If you are wanting to prevent the repeated `getElementById()` calls, you could do something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('el').style;
el.display = "inline";
el.backgroundColor = "#000000";
```

or arguably more readable and semantically more correct:

```
var el = document.getElementById('el');
el.style.display = "inline";
el.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
```

But that still doesn't solve the one-line problem. I highly recommend jQuery as the others have.