# Add Multiple Styles with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add multiple lines of CSS with JavaScript. I know I can do this:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style
```

as in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But, the above code allows me add just a single CSS Property. If a want to add more than one property, like this:

```
#id1 {
    color: red;
    background-color: beige;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

How do I add all of this by not repeating:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style
```

....again and again. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate with [Change an element's class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript) it's the same principle, check it out

Comment: Please check this Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968593/how-to-set-multiple-css-style-properties-in-javascript, hope it help :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("id1").setAttribute(
  "style", "color: green; background-color: beige; padding-bottom: 2px; margin: 3px;");
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>
  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
Click Me!</button>

</body>
```

Here is a [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2td53t60/)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can add multiple CSS with JavaScript like this

your button

```
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Hello">
```

And the JavaScript for it

```
document.getElementById('myButton')
  .style.cssText = "color: blue; width: 100px; height: 55px; border: 1px solid red;";
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not add a class that has all of the properties defined already?

```
document.getElementById(id).classList.add('new_class')
```

Answer (score 3):

If your styles are dynamically generated and you can't simply add a new `CSS` class to this element, you could do something like this, using the same idea that you posted but coding in a `DRY` manner.

This is also useful if your element already has some styles applied and you don't want to overwrite them.

Click *run code snippet* below to see the demo.

```js
var id  = "content";

var styles = { 
  'color': 'red',
  'background-color': 'beige',
  'padding-bottom': '2px',
  'margin': '3px'
};

var elementStyle = document.getElementById(id).style;
for(var styleName in styles) {
  elementStyle[styleName] = styles[styleName];
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  This is a test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('the_object_ID')
  .setAttribute( 'style', 'color:white; margin:20px;');
```

Comment: You may want to add a little context around the answer.  Also, what if style is already set on the object, and the code should extend that style with additional properties?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function for all this

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunc('id1')"> Click Me! </button>
```

in js

```
function myFunc(id){
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(id);
    myDiv.style.color = 'red';
    myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "beige"; 
    myDiv.style.paddingBottom = "2px";
    myDiv.style.margin = "3px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is using .style like this :

```
document.getElementById("id1").style = "height:30px; width:30px; background-color:red;"
```