# How to use Javascript to add multiple style properties to one element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text-styling

I've tried various renditions of this code to try and change a certain element for a coding exercise but non of them seems to be able to change multiple styling properties of an element on a button click. Would love some assistance. Thanks!

`document.getElementById("Combo Style").onclick = function() {
                    document.getElementById ("More Text").style.fontSize.color = "50px , #BB65C5";
                }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set multiple css style properties in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968593/how-to-set-multiple-css-style-properties-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your expected result use setAttribute
HTML:

```
<button id="Combo Style">Change</button>
<div id="More Text">abcd</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("Combo Style").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("More Text").setAttribute("style", "font-size:50px;color:red;");

}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/AXVWwO

Answer (score 2):

You can use cssText property but it will change the styling for the element completely

[Style cssText Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_csstext.asp)

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.cssText = "background-color:pink;font-size:55px;border:2px dashed green;color:white;"
```

This will overwrite the existing css styling for that element , so make sure you included every needed property.

Answer (score -2):

You need to grab the element by using id or any selector and use style property or css text property to apply css. Check the below code -

```
    var element=document.getElementById("More Text");
    element.style.fontSize="20px";
    element.style.color="red";
    element.style.background="blue";
```

You can also use cssText property, like -

```
document.getElementById("More Text").style.cssText='fontSize="20px";color="red";'
```

This will insert an inline style tag in the element with the csstext property.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".