# javascript styling two effects at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have a bunch of dynamically created div boxes with IDs div1-div999.
I then grab random boxes and change the animation name to "grow". I want to also change the playstate to "running" but as I have it now just randomly selects another group to change the play states for.

```
else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
                 for(var i = 0;i <400; i++){

                     document.getElementById("div"+Math.floor((Math.random()*1000) + 1 )).style.animationName = "Grow";
                     document.getElementById("div"+Math.floor((Math.random()*1000) + 1 )).style.animationPlayState = "running";
                }
            }
```

I would like to change the animation name and play state of just one group selection. Something like:

```
document.getElementById("div"+Math.floor((Math.random()*1000) + 1 )).style.animationName = "Grow" / style.animationPlayState = "running";
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;`...

Comment: is there an issue with storing the random div number into a variable and use it?

Comment: if you want to do the same div 'grow' and 'running' .You should consider stroing Math.floor((Math.random()*1000) + 1 ) in the loop, in a variable and use that to get in document.getelementbyid ,because each time math.random() would generate a different number , you each time in a loop ,you are setting grow to one div and running to another div,is that what you wanted to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set multiple css style properties in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968593/how-to-set-multiple-css-style-properties-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing that random group of div ID's inside an array? Hope this helps.

```
else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
                 for(var i = 0;i <400; i++){

var randomSelection=[]; //a new array to store all ID's
randomSelection[i]=Math.floor((Math.random()*1000) + 1))

document.getElementById("div"+randomSelection[i].style.animationName = "Grow";

document.getElementById("div"+randomSelection[i].style.animationPlayState = "running";
                }
            }
```