# Changing large chunk of style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following function that `reset`s a `button` and applies styling once it is executed:

```
function reset(){
    var boxes = getBoxes();
    for(i = 0 ; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
document.getElementById("start_button").innerHTML = "Start Game";
document.getElementById("start_button").setAttribute('onclick', 'gameStart()');
document.getElementById("start_button").style.color = "black";
document.getElementById("start_button").style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
```

}

However, as you can see, it is getting repetitive to change each style element in the function. Especially if I want this style to be applied:

```
#button{
    text-align: center;
}
#start_button{
    width: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: lightgreen;
    color:black;
}

#start_button:hover {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Is there a way in JavaScript to link to an entire block of style code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968593/how-to-set-multiple-css-style-properties-in-javascript

Comment: why not just add class to element. And set CSS to that class

Comment: So so far you can set it by making a string or setting it to a class. What is best practice in web dev?

Comment: You could add your Style class to the element: `document.getElementById("start_button").className+=" newClass";`
in this case you have to set the `.newClass` style attributes in your css

Comment: So I would declare the new style as:

#start_button clicked{
 [...]
}?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the start_button to a class; which it should be because there will be more than one of them on the page; you can use the className property.

CSS:

```
.start_button{
    width: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: lightgreen;
    color:black;
}

.start_button:hover{
    background:green;
    color: white;
}
```

Look like you are creating buttons so you can grab the buttons
JS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button").className = "start_button";
```