# How to convert a JSON style object to a CSS string?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, inline-styles

I wanted to set my element's style as such:

```
this.refs.element.style = {
    ...this.props.style,
    background: 'blue',
};
```

But apparently you can't use an object to set the ref's style. I have to use a CSS style string with `;` separating the `prop:values`

I'm aware that most people would set style in the render function, but for performance reasons, I can't repeatedly re-render.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A performant answer is to `map` and `join` the `Object.entries` with semicolons:

```
const style = {
  ...this.props.style,
  background: 'blue',
};

const styleString = (
  Object.entries(style).map(([k, v]) => `${k}:${v}`).join(';')
);
```

It unwraps `background:'blue',` to `background:blue;` which works well for CSS

---

To replace any capital letter with dash lowercase letter

```
k = k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, match => `-${match.toLowerCase()}`);
```

Comment: Be aware that properties like backgroundColor should be renamed to background-color, but apart from that, a good use of reduce()!

Comment: @EricSellin good catch, fixed that with a `.replace`, should work but maybe there are edge cases

Comment: but it wont work in IE because IE doesn't support Object.entries()

Comment: This will be rather slow for large objects - you're doing n string concatenations, and each concatenation is on the order of the length of the strings. You'd probably want a map + join instead.

Comment: Who needs IE support in 2021?

Comment: I admit I don't really worry much about IE anymore, but it won't be officially retired until 2022; a reasonably good polyfill for Object.entries is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849831/object-entries-alternative-for-internet-explorer-and-reactjs

Comment: Does your answer support vendor prefixes?

Answer (score 12):

this solution works in IE and handles camelCase keys like backgroundColor

```js
const style = {
    width: '1px',
    height: '1px',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    transform: 'rotateZ(45deg)',
}
const styleToString = (style) => {
    return Object.keys(style).reduce((acc, key) => (
        acc + key.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join('-').toLowerCase() + ':' + style[key] + ';'
    ), '');
};

console.log(styleToString(style));
// output - "width:1px;height:1px;background-color:red;transform:rotateZ(45deg);"
```

Comment: the styleToString function fit good to me

Answer (score 4):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-css. Note it will not add a semicolon to the last property to fix it you can beautify it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssbeautify
Example

```
    const cssbeautify = require('cssbeautify')

    const Css = require('json-to-css')

    const json = {
        "h1": {
            "font-size": "18vw",
            "color": "#f00"
        },
        ".btn": {
            "font-size": "18vw",
            "color": "#f00"
        }
    }


    const r = Css.of(json)
    console.log(r)

    const beautified = cssbeautify(r, {
        autosemicolon: true
    })

    console.log(beautified)
```

Result

```
  console.log src/utils/playground/index.spec.ts:22 // json-to-css
    h1{font-size:18vw;color:#f00}
    .btn{font-size:18vw;color:#f00}

  console.log src/utils/playground/index.spec.ts:29 // cssbeautify
    h1 {
        font-size: 18vw;
        color: #f00;
    }
    
    .btn {
        font-size: 18vw;
        color: #f00;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the great answer of @Artem Bochkarev

I'm adding a snippet to do the opposite conversion as well (string to object) which may come in handy to anyone stumbling here

```js
const style = {
  width: '1px',
  height: '1px',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  transform: 'rotateZ(45deg)',
};
const styleToString = (style) => {
  return Object.keys(style).reduce((acc, key) => (
    acc + key.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join('-').toLowerCase() + ':' + style[key] + ';'
  ), '');
};
const stringToStyle = (style) => {
  const styles = {};
  style.split(';').forEach((s) => {
    const parts = s.split(':', 2);
    if (parts.length > 1) {
      styles[parts[0].trim().replace(/-([a-z])/ig, (_, l) => l.toUpperCase())] = parts[1].trim();
    }
  });
  return styles;
};

console.log(styleToString(style));
// output - "width:1px;height:1px;background-color:red;transform:rotateZ(45deg);"

console.log(stringToStyle(styleToString(style)));
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The problem is that you are overwriting the entire "style" property of the element and losing its prototype and methods. You must add your style object without change the entire property. If you want to apply an object-like style to a DOM element, just do:

```js
Object.assign(this.refs.element.style, {
    background: 'blue',
    color: 'white',
    /** style properties:values goes here */
});
```

Explanation: The property "style" is an instance of the "CSSStyleDeclaration" interface. If you overwrite the interface it wont be a "CSSStyleDeclaration" anymore. It works when you set a string as value because javascript will pass the string directly to the element, without process anything.

CSSStyleDeclaration Reference Doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration

If you want to do a test, go to your navigator > inspector > console and paste the code below:

```js
const p1 = document.createElement('p');
p1.style = { color: 'blue' };

const p2 = document.createElement('p');
Object.assign(p2.style, { color: 'blue' });

console.log(p1);
console.log(p2);
```

The output will be:

```html
<p style=""></p>
<p style="color: blue;"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

the `css` function in `@material-ui/system` can help you out
check [more info](https://material-ui.com/zh/system/basics/) here

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import NoSsr from '@material-ui/core/NoSsr';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { compose, spacing, palette, css } from '@material-ui/system';

const Box = styled.div`
  ${css(
    compose(
      spacing,
      palette,
    ),
  )}
`;

const theme = createMuiTheme();

export default function CssProp() {
  return (
    <NoSsr>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Box color="white" css={{ bgcolor: 'palevioletred', p: 1, textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>
          CssProp
        </Box>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </NoSsr>
  );
}
```