# Object.entries() alternative for Internet Explorer and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Well, I've been building a web application for a couple weeks now, and everything good. I got to the part that I had to test in Internet Explorer, and of all of the things that came up (all fixed except for one), Object.entries() is not supported.

I've been doing some research and try to come up with a simple alternative, but no luck at all.

To be more specific, I'm bringing an object from an API, to fill options for `<select></select>` fields I have to filter some information, just like this:

```
Object.entries(this.state.filterInfo.sectorId).map(this.eachOption)

// Function
eachOption = ([key, val], i) => {
    return(
        <option value={val} key={i}>{val}</option>
    );
}
```

So everything works correctly except for Internet Explorer. The thing is that in this particular component I'm rendering over 30 `<select></select>` fields. IF there is a solution that doesn't require me to rebuild everything, it would be amazing.

Is there a simple solution? A way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you explored loading a polyfill? That is the standard approach to missing functions like this.

Comment: The [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill) is rather trivial.

Comment: `Object.keys(this.state.filterInfo.sectorId).map(this.eachOption,this.state.filterInfo.sectorId)` where you get the value as `this[key]` in the callback

Comment: There's a polyfill shown in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The usual first item to research when you want to use a newer API in an older browser is whether there is a simple polyfill.  And, sure enough there is a pretty simple polyfill for `Object.entries()` shown on the [MDN doc site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill):

```
if (!Object.entries)
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
```

This works for me.

Comment: This worked instead of the "core-js/es6/object" added by default in pollyfills.ts in angular cli generated project

Comment: I had to add `import 'core-js/es/object';`to get it working

Answer (score 3):

Nothing necessarily new to the above answer, but just different code to accomplish the same thing.

Hopefully this helps anyone who stumbles upon this.

```js
// Another approach

const entriesPolyFill = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).map(key => [key, obj[key]]);


// Same thing but easier to read

function entriesPolyFill(obj) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);

    const keyValuePairs = keys.map(key => {
        const value = obj[key];
        
        return [key, value];
    });
    
    return keyValuePairs;
 };
 
 
// Possible usage if you don't want to alter Object class:
// Ex: Need key-value pairs to iterate over
const entries = (Object.entries ? Object.entries(obj) : entriesPolyFill(obj));

// Then do whatever you want with the Array
// ---> entries.map(), entries.filter(), etc..

// You could also move the whole thing to a function
// and always call the function so you don't have to
// write excess ternary operators in your code:

// -- In a utils file somewhere else...
export function getEntries(obj) {
  return Object.entries ? Object.entries(obj) : Object.keys(obj).map(key => [key, obj[key]]);
}

// Wherever you need to get entries in you project
import { getEntries } from "<path to utils>";

...

const entries = getEntries(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise polyfill using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
if(!Object.entries) 
    Object.entries = function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(arr, key) {
            arr.push([key, obj[key]]);
            return arr;
        }, []);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shim/polyfill like this one: https://github.com/es-shims/Object.entries