# Javascript - Combining arrays and keeping same indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, cross-browser

I am attempting to combine 3 arrays of objects while keeping the same indexes of the original array. I am able to accomplish this by using a `spread operator` method. My current issue is that I am running into issue on internet explorer due to its compatibility. I've been unable to find another way of doing this without using a `spread operator` method. Is this something that can be done with a method that is compatible with internet explorer?

Here is the current code that I am using :

```js
const revenueArr = [{title: 'online', revenue: 34321, revenueGrowth: 3.2},{title: 'retail', revenue: 321, revenueGrowth: 1.2} ] 

const employArr = [ { employGrowth: 0.2 }, {employGrowth: -1.2} ]


const businessArr = [ {businessGrowth: 2.8}, {businessGrowth: 1.6} ] 


const allData = revenueArr.map((it, index) => {
    return { ...it, ...employArr[index], ...businessArr[index]}
}) 

console.log(allData)
```

My expected outcome is the console.log above in the code snippet, where the first index of objects remain the first index after combining them together. Such as:

```
[
  {
    "title": "online",
    "revenue": 34321,
    "revenueGrowth": 3.2,
    "employGrowth": 0.2,
    "businessGrowth": 2.8
  },
  {
    "title": "retail",
    "revenue": 321,
    "revenueGrowth": 1.2,
    "employGrowth": -1.2,
    "businessGrowth": 1.6
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` as a replacement for the spread operator. `Object.assign()` is also not available in Internet Explorer, but you can use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) since it's not new syntax.

```js
// Object.assign polyfill for Internet Explorer

if (typeof Object.assign !== 'function') {
  // Must be writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true
  Object.defineProperty(Object, "assign", {
    value: function assign(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
      'use strict';
      if (target === null || target === undefined) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);

      for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[index];

        if (nextSource !== null && nextSource !== undefined) { 
          for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
            // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
              to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}

const revenueArr = [{title: 'online', revenue: 34321, revenueGrowth: 3.2},{title: 'retail', revenue: 321, revenueGrowth: 1.2} ] 

const employArr = [ { employGrowth: 0.2 }, {employGrowth: -1.2} ]


const businessArr = [ {businessGrowth: 2.8}, {businessGrowth: 1.6} ] 


const allData = revenueArr.map((it, index) => {
    return Object.assign({}, it, employArr[index], businessArr[index]);
}) 

console.log(allData)
```

Comment: when using a polyfill is it as simple as copying and pasting the code from mdn into my code? Or am I altering with based off the code snippet you provided? Not sure on how to implement the polyfill

Comment: here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r842yfgt/  as an example.

Comment: The polyfill just defines `Object.assign()` when it's not already available. That's in addition to the code in my snippet that uses the function in place of spread.

Comment: You need to define the polyfill *before* you try to call it. It should be at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` should give you the same output, with support for legacy browsers.

```js
const allData1 = revenueArr.map((it, index) => {
  return { ...it, ...employArr[index], ...businessArr[index] } // using spread
})

console.log(allData1)

const allData2 = revenueArr.map((it, index) => {
  return Object.assign({}, it, employArr[index], businessArr[index]) // using Object.assign
})

console.log(allData2) // same as allData1
```

You may find this useful https://thecodebarbarian.com/object-assign-vs-object-spread.html

Answer (score 0):

this should be supported everywhere:

```
revenueArr.map((it, index) => {
    let r = {};
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(it))
        r[key] = value;
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(employArr[index]))
        r[key] = value;
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(businessArr[index]))
        r[key] = value;
    return r;
})
```

using the following polyfill:

```
if (!Object.entries)
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
  };
```

(Credits: [@jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849831/object-entries-alternative-for-internet-explorer-and-reactjs))