# How to solve CSS2Properties doesn't have an indexed property setter for '0' error on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a div element throught Javascript and I want to copy the styles of the canvas initialized by a game engine that I'm using. I used Object.assign to achieve this and it works perfectly on Chrome, but when I tested on Firefox I got this error and it doesn't allow me to continue with my game. I'm leaving the function code below:

```
export const addCanvasOverlay = (id) => {
  const canvas = game.system.canvas;
  const overlay = document.createElement('DIV');
  overlay.id = id;
  /**
   * Clone canvas style to ensure the overlay is always over it
   */
  const trackCanvasSize = () => {
    Object.assign(overlay.style, canvas.style);
    overlay.style['pointer-events'] = 'none';
  };
  window.addEventListener('resize', trackCanvasSize);
  trackCanvasSize();
  canvas.parentNode.appendChild(overlay);
  return overlay;
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

This is what I get on canvas.style besides the style normal properties:

[image: canvas.style]

Comment: it all depends on the canvas.style ... it looks like it has a property "0"? Can you try iterating on all its properties and adding them one by one, with a console.log to know which one is getting added. This will help you figure out which property is make it crash.

Comment: @Salketer I added a screenshot of the Firefox inspector on that object. It shows all the normal CSS properties but also the numbered properties shown in the image. Do you know why does this happen?

Comment: I couldn't find any spec about that... Not sure if Firefox is right or wrong. Seems like you'll have to work on a mechanism to inherit the correct properties only... You could loop through each enumerable, and test if it's an int, if it is, just do not put it in the new style.

Comment: the problem seems to be that chrome defines the number indices as nun-enumerable and the normal keys (css style attributes) as enumerable. Firefox does exact the opposite: "0" is there enumerable. and "width" not. Couldn't find anything about it in the W3 specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I solved it doing this, I had to check constructor of the style object and make an additional step on Firefox:

```
let styles = {};
switch (canvas.style.constructor.name) {
      // Fix for firefox
      case 'CSS2Properties':
        Object.values(canvas.style).forEach((prop) => {
          styles[prop] = canvas.style[prop];
        });
        break;
      case 'CSSStyleDeclaration':
        styles = canvas.style;
        break;
      default:
        console.error('Unknown style object prototype');
        break;
    }
Object.assign(overlay.style, styles);
```