# es6 object destructuring not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to assign styles to an object. Initial code was

```
targetEl.style.top = `${top}px` ;
targetEl.style.display = 'block';
targetEl.style.background = `url(${this.props.imgSrc}) no-repeat`;
targetEl.style.backgroundSize = "1800px 900px";
```

I tried to use es6 destructuring and rewrote the code like this:

```
targetEl.style = {...targetEl.style, 
                      top:`${top}px`, 
                      display: 'block', 
                      background: `url(${this.props.imgSrc}) no-repeat`, 
                      backgroundSize:  "1800px 900px" };
```

But for some reason it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doubt you can overwrite the whole style object. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: .style is read-only. Maybe `Object.assign(targetEl.style, { top: `${top}px` } )`. Also, it's type is not object

Comment: Its not an Object destructuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using destructuring, you are using experimental spread syntax in an object literal which creates a new object. You might be used to that when working with immutable data frameworks, but here you really want to *assign* properties of the `targetEl.style` [CSS declaration object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration). You do not want to *replace* the whole `.style` object with a new one.

Try [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with a plain literal:

```
Object.assign(targetEl.style, {
    top: `${top}px`, 
    display: 'block', 
    background: `url(${this.props.imgSrc}) no-repeat`, 
    backgroundSize: '1800px 900px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, it's a bit more efficient without `Object.assign`:

```js
const s = targetEl.style; 
s.top = `${top}px`; 
s.display = 'block'; 
s.background = `url(${this.props.imgSrc}) no-repeat`; 
s.backgroundSize = '1800px 900px';
```

but even more efficient to assign them all at once ([How can I set multiple CSS styles in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968593/how-can-i-set-multiple-css-styles-in-javascript)) :

```js
targetEl.style.cssText += `; top = ${top}px, display = 'block', 
    background = url(${this.props.imgSrc}) no-repeat, backgroundSize = '1800px 900px'; `;
```