# Change CSS with properties defined in an object

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it at all possible to dynamically style elements using CSS properties that are stored within a JS object?

For example, changing both the `width` and `background` of a simple `<div>` element:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

The box is initally styled with:

```
div {
  background: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

The box will be restyled when clicking the button element as so:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Code to change box style here...
}
```

I have seen the use of `setAttribute('style', 'some style stuff here');`, however I have come to understand that this will simply replace ALL of the style attribute associated with the element, rather than appending/changing the properties defined within :-(

My goal here is to do hold CSS properties in a JS object such as:

```
const myStyle = {
  'background': 'green',
  'width': '20px'
}
```

and apply this to the element.

I know this can be done by holding the properties in another CSS class named something like '.box-transform' and then adding that to the classList of the element... But I am wanting to do this through JS.

My initial attempt was something along the lines of:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(myStyle)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${val}`)
  box.setAttribute('style', `${key}: ${val}`)
}
});
```

However I was running into the issue of the overriding nature of `setAttribute`...

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const box = document.getElementById('b');

const myobj = {
  'width': '20px',
  'background': 'yellow'
};

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(myobj)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${val}`)
  box.setAttribute('style', `${key}: ${val}`)
}
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="b"></div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Just use `box.style[key] = val;` instead. (without that, the solution would be to combine all properties into a single CSS string, then set that as `style`)

Comment: Ah amazing! I knew it would be something like this. I had tried `.style.${key}` before like a dunce... If you post as an answer, I will give you some karma ;-)

Comment: FYI IE won't recognize these `() => {}` ````${key}````

Comment: @AbhishekPandey that's what Babel is for ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set multiple CSS styles in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968593/how-can-i-set-multiple-css-styles-in-javascript)

Comment: @ChrisG Now I understand the `cssText` property, yes it does. I saw that answer earlier and was confused as the CSS properties specified were all written inline and looked horrendous... A colleague pointed out their own usage using backticks to place each property on a separate line. Looks much cleaner!

Comment: You have to scroll down a bit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968677/5734311) which should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const box = document.getElementById('b');

const myobj = {
  'width': '200px',
  'background': 'yellow'
};

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(myobj)) {
    box.style[key] = val;
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="b"></div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Good answer obviously, but not upvoting this since question is a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

You can first generate the CSS as string then use `cssText` property:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const box = document.getElementById('b');

const myobj = {
  'width': '20px',
  'background': 'yellow'
};

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var cssText ='';
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(myobj)) {
    cssText += `${key}: ${val};`  
  }
  box.style.cssText =  cssText;
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="b"></div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

You can also update the style with the object *key* and *value* inside the loop:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const box = document.getElementById('b');

const myobj = {
  'width': '20px',
  'background': 'yellow'
};

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var cssText ='';
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(myobj)) {
    box.style[key] = val;  
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="b"></div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: This works but setting `box.style[key]` directly is much more readable (and better practice).

Comment: @ChrisG, included that as part pf the answer, thanks:)

Comment: @ChrisG applying a style in each iteration is segnificantly more expensive than concatenating in each iteration and applying only at the end. This may not matter in many cases, but should be noted for cases when efficiency matters.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a number of ways of we can apply styles from a JavaScript object to an element's style attribute.

For the most concise syntax where ES6 is acceptable we can use `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(elem.style, stylesObject);
```

We can also convert the styles object to an array with `Object.entries` then use `map` to convert each key-value to an appropriate string and finally, join the strings together using `join`:

```
elem.style = Object.entries(stylesObject).map(x => `${x[0]}:${x[1]}`).join(';');
```

**We can also concatenate a string using various `for` loops.**

We can use `for in`:

```
let str = '';
for (let style in stylesObject) {
    str += `${style}:${stylesObject[style]};`;
}
elem.style = str;
```

or we can use `forEach`:

```
let str = '';
Object.entries(stylesObject).forEach(style => {
    str += `${style[0]}:${style[1]};`;
})
elem.style = str;
```

or we can use `for of`:

```
let str = '';
for (let style of Object.entries(stylesObject)) {
    str += `${style[0]}:${style[1]};`;
}
elem.style = str;
```

and finally, we can also use a regular good ol' `for` loop:

```
const stylesArray = Object.entries(stylesObject);
let str = '';
for (let x = 0; x < stylesArray.length; x++) {
    str += `${stylesArray[x][0]}:${stylesArray[x][1]};`;
}
elem.style = str;
```

You can check out this [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/p3l5bhr2bg/1) tests I put together to see how these options affect performance.

[For the curious, you can see [version 2 of the benchmark](https://jsbench.me/p3l5bhr2bg/2) tests, where I added more variations (most of the additions is just changing `Object.entries` to `Object.keys`).]

I left out the option of applying the style in each loop iteration instead of concatenating to a string, because, as you can see in the [benchmarks](https://jsbench.me/p3l5bhr2bg/1), that is significantly more expensive.