# Grouping css styles under one dom selection in JS

Tags: javascript, grouping

I've got this code:

```
let myId = document.getElementById('myID');
myId.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
myId.style.color = 'green';
```

Is there a way to group all css code in one group omitting the "myId.style" prefix? Like in {}?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
myId.style.cssText = "display: block; position: absolute";
```

or maybe with es6 like this:

````
myId.style.cssText = ```
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
```
````

This question was already mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968772/3865116