# How to change multiple CSS styles with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change multiple CSS styles using JavaScript. I have a button clicking which should result in changing the `color` and `font-size` of the `<p>`.

```css
button {color: white; background-color: black; border: none; padding: 10px 20px; transition-duration: .5s; cursor: pointer;}
button:hover {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Changing multiple styles</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById("demo").style.cssText = "fontSize: 35px; color: blue">Click Me!</button>
```

However, clicking the button gives me the following error:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 120
}
```

I did exactly what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968772) suggested to a similar question. How to fix this error?

Comment: @pavel: How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not close the `onclick` declaration with `"`.

Also, inside the `onclick` use `'` single quotes.

You either use single quotes as 'quote wrapping' and double quotes inside them either you use double quotes and single quotes inside.

But i suggest you use a different approach and toggle a className on the element. And style that className.

See second button

```css
button {color: white; background-color: black; border: none; padding: 10px 20px; transition-duration: .5s; cursor: pointer;}
button:hover {background-color: blue;}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Changing multiple styles</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.cssText = 'font-size: 35px; color: blue'">Click Me!</button>


<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').classList.toggle('blue')">Click Me 2!</button>
```

Comment: The font-size is still not changing at the same time as the colour. Is it just me or is it the same for you?

Comment: i changed it. it's `font-size` not `fontSize`. But again, i suggest you use the second solution

Answer (score 1):

Just change the button code to this

```
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.cssText = 'font-size: 35px; color: blue'">Click Me!</button>
```

U did closed the onclick function