# What is the difference between HTMLStyleElement and CSSStyleElement

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I'm been digging a little in Style Sheets, I was trying to access a `<style>` tag the same way I could access a **styleSheet** element, for example.

```
<style id="myStyle">
</style>

var myStyle = document.getElementById("myStyle");
alert(myStyle.cssRules[0]);
```

But this didn't work, then I decided to check the type of the `<style>` tag.

```
alert(myStyle);
```

And it gave me this :

```
[object HTMLStyleElement]
```

So I checked the type of a styleSheet.

```
alert(document.styleSheets[0]);
```

And it gave me this:

`[object CSSStyleElement]`

So what is the real difference? And how can I access the rules in `<style>` tag other than using `.innerHTML`? And how can I create a new `styleSheet`?

Comment: For creating new stylesheet look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a big difference actually.

[HTMLStyleElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement) is actually a flavor of [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) - a wrapper containing some DOM structure. What's great about it is that it implements [LinkStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LinkStyle) interface as well, therefore giving us ability to access its underlying `stylesheet` (via `sheet` property).

[CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), on the contrary, is not related to DOM - it's a specific wrapper for CSS style sheets (containing CSS rules). It lets you manipulate CSS styling via [deleteRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule) and [insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) methods, or by changing an existing rule (via `style` property).

Answering your specific question, check the following:

HTML:

```
<style id="myStyle">
    p { background-color: lime; }
</style>
```

JS:

```
var myStyle = document.getElementById("myStyle");
alert(myStyle.sheet.cssRules[0].cssText);
```

As you see, here we first access CSSStyleSheet wrapped by `#myStyle` element, then access its specific rule ([CSSRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule)), then - its text.

P.S. I wrote a small [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XuN9k/) illustrating how one can manipulate stylesheets dynamically. It's not pretty, and by a reason: changing presentation by swapping classes is far better technique. Still, it can be done even this way. )

Comment: Glad to help, check the demo as well. )