# jQuery hover each different background color

Tags: jquery, background, hover

How to `hover` every different `background-color`?
These code set the background-color is working:

```
var dlcabgColors = [
    'rgb(233, 147, 26)', 'rgb(22, 145, 190)', 'rgb(22, 107, 162)' , 'rgb(27, 54, 71)'
];

var i = 0;
$('.abc').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', dlcabgColors[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % dlcabgColors.length;
});
```

But when I add *hover function*,the function will repeat all background-color.

I want to specify the elements of a specified color, not repeat all background color

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MotoTony/fSBDD/3/)

As always, your assistance is appreciated!


Thanks!every one:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?
 <kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fSBDD/12/)**</kbd>
Depending on the index 0f the hovered one change the color to match the array position:

```
var dlC = [
    'rgb(233, 147, 26)',
    'rgb(22, 145, 190)',
    'rgb(22, 107, 162)',
    'rgb(27, 54, 71)'
];
var dlH= [
    '#000',                    /* only difference... why that? */
    'rgb(22, 145, 190)',
    'rgb(22, 107, 162)',
    'rgb(27, 54, 71)'
];

$('.abc').each(function( i ) {
   $(this).css({backgroundColor : dlC[i] })
          .on("mouseenter mouseleave",function( e ) {
              $(this).css({backgroundColor : e.type=="mouseenter" ? dlH[i] : dlC[i] });
          });
});
```

the `? :` I used is a Ternary Operator. You can Goog for it if you don't know how the logic works.

Comment: Yes,Thanks, Roko ,but how change default background-color is dlHColors,not white?

Comment: because the element very strange,i don't know why can't change the css,no any !important there,after this jquery works,i'll figure out

Comment: @MotoTony sorry, I had some errors, edited my code for better! ;)

Comment: @MotoTony removed the `index()` stuff cause it was not needed once we return `index` (i) from the `each` argument

Answer (score 3):

You should do that with CSS only, the only thing you need to is create proper classes for it and then add them to your elements. i.e.:

```
var totalColors = 4;

$('.abc').each(function(i, e) {
    $(this).addClass("color"+i%totalColors);
});

.color1:hover { background: #0FF }
.color2:hover { background: #FF0 }
.color3:hover { background: #0F0 }
.color0:hover { background: #F00 }
```

Edit: minor fix and here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CxmGp/

Edit2: you can also generate the css classes directly through javascript: [How to dynamically create CSS class in JavaScript and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply)