# Can't Get Styles in Non-Webkit Browsers with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, webkit

I'm using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/5830517#5830517) to pull the style information for an element on a page, and then apply those styles to a second element, but for some reason, it's only working in Chrome and Safari [not Firefox or Internet Explorer]. This is problematic, because I mainly need this for Internet Explorer.

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J3tSx/1/

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function css(a) {
        var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
        for (var i in sheets) {
            var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
            for (var r in rules) {
                if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                    o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
                }
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
    function css2json(css) {
        var s = {};
        if (!css) return s;
        if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
            for (var i in css) {
                if ((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                    s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
                }
            }
        } else if (typeof css == "string") {
            css = css.split("; ");
            for (var i in css) {
                var l = css[i].split(": ");
                s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
    /*
    $("#test_div").click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
        if (!$(this).hasClass("hovered")) {
            alert("detected no hovered class");
            $(this).addClass("hovered");
            alert("added hovered class");
            var hoverStyle = css($("#test_div"));
            alert("created the hoverStyle variable");
            $("#second_div").css(hoverStyle);
            alert("applied the hoverStyle variable to #second_div");
        }
    });
    */
    var hoverStyle = css($("#test_div"));
    alert("created the hoverStyle variable");
    $("#second_div").css(hoverStyle);
    alert("applied the hoverStyle variable to #second_div");
});
```

HTML:

```
<section id="test_div">
</section>
<section id="second_div">
</section>
```

UPDATE: What's weird is that neither IE nor Firefox throw any kind of error. They just act as if `#test_div` is unstyled, and therefore no styles get added to `#second_div`. Very strange.

UPDATE 2: I just noticed this bit of code:

```
var s = {};
if (!css) return s;
```

I think this may have something to do with it.

Things I've tried

- Changing the names of the sections, to get rid of the _
- Changing to an older version of jQuery
- Moving the position of the code from the body to the head, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that function wasn't getting all of the styles of the element in IE and FireFox. You can use `console.log(hoverStyle)` to view what styles were being retrieved. It appears only `color`, `height`, and `width` were being pulled in FireFox.

Try this solution provided as the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416527/1506980). (make sure to upvote the original post!)

```
/*
 * getStyleObject Plugin for jQuery JavaScript Library
 * From: http://upshots.org/?p=112
 */

(function($){
    $.fn.getStyleObject = function(){
        var dom = this.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            };
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            };
            return returns;
        };
        if(style = dom.currentStyle){
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            };
            return returns;
        };
        return this.css();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This works in FireFox and IE: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J3tSx/3/).

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I'll definitely upvote the original answer as well. One more thing: I'd like to have these styles apply to a class that I can then toggle with jQuery. Is this possible, or would I need to just clear the inline styles, then regenerate them every time?

Comment: You can dynamically create CSS classes with JavaScript, but it's not recommended: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply). IMO this seems like a good use case for inline styles. Good luck =D