# How can we solve dynamic inline style issue for CSP in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using React 0.12.2 in one of project.We have implemented Csp. Now Csp is blocking inline style. If inline style is static then we can easily move in separate css file but in our project, some of inline style is dynamic.So we cannot move.

I have gone through following link but I am not sure , How can I use in react. Is it good way or not ?

[CSP - How to solve style-src unsafe-inline -when having dynamically positioned page elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564674/csp-how-to-solve-style-src-unsafe-inline-when-having-dynamically-positioned-p/51592893)

Any help will be appreciated.