# Content-Security-Policy and SVG's with external <use>

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, content-security-policy

I have set up my Content-Security-Policy (CSP) with the following definition for `style-src`:

```
style-src 'self' 'nonce-somenonce'
```

Then, in my markup I include SVG's like this:

```
<svg role="img" title="Clock">
    <use xlink:href="/Content/Styles/svg/sprite.symbol.svg#icon-clock" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
</svg>
```

The external SVG contains multiple symbols with paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 40 40" id="arrow-right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M29 20l-5-5v4H11v2h13v4l5-5z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 22 22" id="icon-clock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill="#c20418" class="atcls-1" d="M17.727 9.777h-5.5v-5.5a1.222 ..."/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Chrome refuses to allow this code, and I'm not sure how to allow it without `'unsafe-inline'`. SVG is not a nonceable element according to these two tests:

1. [Test of CSP: 'nonce-value' - is element nonceable?](https://csplite.com/csp/test187/#test)
2. [Test of CSP: How to make  CSP compliant](https://csplite.com/csp/test381/)

I looked at [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/108148) thread, which suggests grouping the SVG into a `<style>` and nonce it, but I can't find out how to do this, and whether it works with an external definition.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29089970/2102106) thread suggesting to use JS to set the style, but I again can't find how this would work with SVG's and `<use>`.

A report generated by the browser looks like this:

```
{
  "csp-report": {
    "document-uri": "https://mypage.xyz/content/styles/svg/sprite.symbol.svg",
    "referrer": "",
    "violated-directive": "style-src-elem",
    "effective-directive": "style-src-elem",
    "original-policy": "default-src 'self';script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-LwpcXyjstsjZdWhOBquhhaxTEe+TFHbaAKYGal+sV3I=' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http: https:;style-src 'self' 'nonce-LwpcXyjstsjZdWhOBquhhaxTEe+TFHbaAKYGal+sV3I=' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com;child-src 'self';connect-src 'self';img-src 'self';frame-src 'self';object-src 'none';font-src 'self';media-src 'self';manifest-src 'self';prefetch-src 'self';worker-src 'none';base-uri 'self';form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self';upgrade-insecure-requests;report-uri /api/csp-reports",
    "disposition": "report",
    "blocked-uri": "inline",
    "line-number": 1,
    "source-file": "https://mypage.xyz/content/styles/svg/sprite.symbol.svg",
    "status-code": 0,
    "script-sample": ""
  }
}
```

Adding `style-src-elem` to the header also does not solve it, even though the report states that this directive is violated. And this is also [not implemented in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src-elem) at all. In Chrome, I get the following error which is contradicting since a nonce is clearly defined, even in the error message:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-Ma4zjvbuXdD3iwOLjAXsiJ2Qqk2TvVEQlT1efIY+qgE='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Ptir/SKEXaGsdPsQ11Srj5YgYg3GDQ1ZV8flKlU21lI='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Why do you think SVG is not a nonceable element?

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson, I initially deleted my question because I thought you were right and didn't have time to try it out until now. I added links to two tests that test <svg>'s with CSP, and the conclusion is that <svg> elements are not nonceable. I verified this myself by adding nonces to the elements, but it has no effect. Maybe it is browser specific whether there is support for it? I can't find a resource for this though.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with with the nonce code but there does seem to be some here: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/svg/SVGElement.cpp

Comment: @RobertLongson That's interesting, because I did also test it in Firefox with the same result. There is also no mention of the nonce attribute on the <svg> element on the Mozilla Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg or anywhere else. I updated my question to include a CSP report generated by the browser for one of the SVG's used in this way, with a nonce added. Edit: I actually just noticed myself the report references "style-src-elem", not "style-src". I will try to add that to the header and see whether that works.

Comment: I added the style-src-elem directive to the CSP header, but without success. I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

The code like:

```
<svg>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 40 40" id="arrow-right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M29 20l-5-5v4H11v2h13v4l5-5z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

when it's embedded from external SVG via `<use>` definitely does [not require](https://csplite.com/csp/test406/) `'unsafe-inline'` in the `style-src`.
You have a *style=* attribute used somewhere in this external SVG.

Since you are using CSP reporting, just add a [`'report-sample'`](https://csplite.com/csp103/) token into `style-src` directive and you'll see a sample of code that cause a violation.

Note that there is a major inconsistency in the behavior of Chrome and Firefox browsers when embedding external SVGs by `<use>`.
 Inline styles in the *style=* attribute embedded by external `<use>` do not breach CSP in Firefox, but breach it in Chrome. And in the same time Crome apply an inline *style=* despite the CSP violation.
 Inline event handlers built-in tags in the external SVG cause a CSP violation in the Firefox and are blocked, whereas in Chrome these do not cause CSP violations, but are not executed at all.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it is really helpful. You are most likely right about the inline styles being inside the SVG, I will check to confirm later. I also didn't know about the report sampling, that could come in handy too. Considering the inconsistentcy across browsers, I will try and find a way to include these styles in a different way and will update my question with whether I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am working through Jonas Schmedtmann's complete-node-bootcamp on Udemy.
I have the same error using Chrome Version, 103.0.5060.114
Using helmet, ^5.0.2

The error I have in Chrome is:
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: `"style-src 'self'...`

The problem comes from a `icons.svg` file provided with the course. The first line of the .svg file is:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

I have solved the error by removing the inline style and attributes:

```
 style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
```

from the first line of the .svg file.

The remaining line is:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true"  version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

I simply added the style I removed from the .svg file to a code block in the style.css file.

```
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

My app.js helmet CSP:

```
app.use(
helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
useDefaults: false,
directives: {
  defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
  connectSrc: ["'self'", 'ws://127.0.0.1:*'],
  scriptSrc: [
    "'self'",
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js',
    'ajax.googleapis.com *'
  ],
  styleSrc: ["'self'", 'fonts.googleapis.com', 'w3.org/*'],
  fontSrc: ['fonts.gstatic.com'],
  upgradeInsecureRequests: []
}
})
);
```