# Is it possible to select attributes with vendor prefixes with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the Thumb color for my slider, but I need to select the thumb with '.topcoat-range-input::-webkit-slider-thumb'. This selector is not working with css, I think because it includes a vendor prefix. Is there a possibility to fix that issue?
I want to pick the color dynamically, so I  can't simply append a class.

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.topcoat-range-input::-webkit-slider-thumb').css('background', 'rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qcn6tmpz/3/

A possible solution would be this one, but i hoped on simple way to do this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $("<style type='text/css'>.topcoat-range-input::-webkit-slider-thumb{background:rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)}</style>").appendTo($("head"));
});
```

Comment: why dont you just apply a class which defines the CSS rule with pseudo selector...

Comment: Because I want to change the color dynamically, actually I pick the color from an image and set it to the thumb.

Comment: Does this :::[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/f6Z3D/)::: Help? Found this on google, a simple function that lets you get browser specific CSS styles names properties, and then apply styles to it via cssProp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the class on click and have your CSS rule defined for the selector. 
Updated fiddle here.  http://jsfiddle.net/qcn6tmpz/9/

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.topcoat-range-input').addClass('applied');
});


.topcoat-range-input.applied::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background : rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: For sure, the problem here is, that I change the color dynamically in the code

Comment: Do u have the definite list of colors, if yes you can just define the class for them and use it. If you dont have the definite colors and u get them dynamically then you can have look at this to create class dynamically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply/8630641#8630641 I know bit too much for this small problem...

Comment: Well it seems that there is no simple solution for this simple problem, but I think I will use this solution : $('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $("<style type='text/css'>.topcoat-range-input::-webkit-slider-thumb{background:rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)}</style>").appendTo($("head"));
});

Comment: link I shared in comment does the same thing of creating class at the run time, which is what your solution is doing. I would have gone for my solution, cause thats clear and clean...

Comment: So can you help me with the implementation? I tried it this way, but it is not working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/qcn6tmpz/10/

Comment: Adding important to the rule made it work. Needed it for overriding previous rule. http://jsfiddle.net/qcn6tmpz/11/

Answer (score 0):

For FYI:
You can't do it the way you want
the way vishvanath do it is the only best way you can do it.

reason:
'::' <- this is not accepted by jquery selectore parser so even if you backslash them like

$('.topcoat-range-input//://:-webkit-slider-thumb').css('background', 'rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)');

still wont work because as per w3 guidelines:
"Style sheet preprocessors must not remove these backslashes from a style sheet since that would change the style sheet's meaning."

For your problem of choosing colour dynamically
Use Less css and then pass colour in the ass class function of vishwanath

Comment: Could you tell me what's wrong with my code here? http://jsfiddle.net/qcn6tmpz/10/