# Is it possible to change the CSS translate distance value from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code in css:

```css
/*Animation Styles*/
.anim1 {
  -webkit-animation: anim1 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: anim1 5s;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes anim1 {
  to {
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes anim1 {
  to {
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to change `0px` to something else via javascript?

---

Here's my current attempt -- [referencing this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720483/2016196):

```
// Setup animation classes
var setupAnimClasses = function(){
    var caroWidth = caroWrapper.offsetWidth;
    var caroHeight = caroWrapper.offsetHeight;
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';

    for(var i in pageQueue){
        var caroX = caroWidth * i; 
        style.innerHTML += "\
            .caroAnimp"+i+" {\n\
                -webkit-animation: animp"+i+" 0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */\n\
                animation: animp"+i+" 5s;\n\
            }\n\
            @-webkit-keyframes animp"+i+" {\n\
                to {\n\
                    -webkit-transform:translateX("+caroX+"px);\n\
                    -ms-transform:translateX("+caroX+"px);\n\
                    transform:translateX("+caroX+"px);\n\
                }\n\
            @keyframes animp"+i+" {\n\
                to {\n\
                    background: yellow;\n\
                    -webkit-transform:translateX("+caroX+"px);\n\
                    -ms-transform:translateX("+caroX+"px);\n\
                    transform:translateX("+caroX+"px);\n\
                }\n\
            }\n";
    }

    style.setAttribute('class','caroAnimStyles');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
};
setupAnimClasses();
```

This runs fine and produces:

```
.caroAnimp0 {
    -webkit-animation: animp0 0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: animp0 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animp0 {
    to {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(0px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(0px);
        transform:translateX(0px);
    }
@keyframes animp0 {
    to {
        background: yellow;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(0px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(0px);
        transform:translateX(0px);
    }
}
.caroAnimp1 {
    -webkit-animation: animp1 0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: animp1 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animp1 {
    to {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(1434px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(1434px);
        transform:translateX(1434px);
    }
@keyframes animp1 {
    to {
        background: yellow;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(1434px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(1434px);
        transform:translateX(1434px);
    }
}
.caroAnimp2 {
    -webkit-animation: animp2 0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: animp2 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animp2 {
    to {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(2868px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(2868px);
        transform:translateX(2868px);
    }
@keyframes animp2 {
    to {
        background: yellow;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(2868px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(2868px);
        transform:translateX(2868px);
    }
}
.caroAnimp3 {
    -webkit-animation: animp3 0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: animp3 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animp3 {
    to {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(4302px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(4302px);
        transform:translateX(4302px);
    }
@keyframes animp3 {
    to {
        background: yellow;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(4302px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(4302px);
        transform:translateX(4302px);
    }
}
.caroAnimp4 {
    -webkit-animation: animp4 0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: animp4 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animp4 {
    to {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(5736px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(5736px);
        transform:translateX(5736px);
    }
@keyframes animp4 {
    to {
        background: yellow;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(5736px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(5736px);
        transform:translateX(5736px);
    }
}
.caroAnimp5 {
    -webkit-animation: animp5 0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: animp5 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animp5 {
    to {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(7170px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(7170px);
        transform:translateX(7170px);
    }
@keyframes animp5 {
    to {
        background: yellow;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(7170px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(7170px);
        transform:translateX(7170px);
    }
}
```

However, when using this code:

`$("tag")[0].setAttribute('class','caroAnimp1')`, nothing happens.

It doesn't matter what tag I try this on, nothing happens. The only time something happens if it there was a class applied and the settings got removed at the class change.

Comment: yes ... you can change it directly or by changing the class...

Comment: If you are able to change the CSS, there would be a better way of doing this using `transition` on the `transform` property, then applying your new transform property inline using javascript.

Comment: How would I access the property `@keyframes anim1 { to { transform: translateX(0px)...` in order to change it to say `translateX(400px)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to accomplish this:
For Example:

```
$(<myelement>).css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(0px, 70px)');
```

Comment: The issue with jQuery is that I do now know of a way to use jQuery functions on a specific dom element, like `$("div")[0]` or `document.getElementById('div1')`

Answer (score 0):

Either you jQuery's CSS property

```
$('.anim1').css({"-webkit-transform":"translate(0px,70px)"});​
```

Or you can use the *addClass* method.

Define the CSS transition:

### CSS

```
.animate{
    -webkit-transform:translate(0px,70px);
}
```

### jQuery

```
 $('.anim1').addClass('.animate');
```

Comment: Is this possible in vanilla JS?