# cal-heatmap - legendColors as array of color values?

Tags: d3.js, cal-heatmap

I am trying out cal-heatmap, and I want to supply a simple array of the legend colors to use, rather than having to define CSS classes for each color.

So far in my testing this doesn't seem possible?

for example, using:

```
legendColors : ['rgb(103,0,31)','rgb(178,24,43)','rgb(214,96,77)','rgb(244,165,130)','rgb(253,219,199)','rgb(224,224,224)','rgb(186,186,186)','rgb(135,135,135)','rgb(77,77,77)','rgb(26,26,26)'],
```

Gives me a scale with 10 steps from the first to the second color, ignoring the rest.

Am I missing something simple in the documentation, or is this not possible?

I know that I can create CSS classes, but I don't want to do that - I need to have a dynamic, variable number of categories, with dynamically created colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the API and source code and it doesn't seem possible.  Two thoughts come to mind:

One, fix it after the fact:

```
 cal.init({
   range: 10,
   start: new Date(2000, 0, 1, 1),
   data: "datas-hours.json",
   onComplete: function() {
     setTimeout(function(){
       ['rgb(103,0,31)','rgb(178,24,43)','rgb(214,96,77)','rgb(244,165,130)','rgb(253,219,199)','rgb(224,224,224)','rgb(186,186,186)','rgb(135,135,135)','rgb(77,77,77)','rgb(26,26,26)']
        .forEach(function(d,i){               
           d3.selectAll("rect.r" + i)
             .style("fill", d);
           });
        }, 10);
  }
```

I'm not sure why the setTimeout is necessary and this produces an odd "flash" affect as the colors are swapped.  Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kQ7bMzOdO2nlyetExAF2?p=preview).

Another idea is to write [the styles on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720483/16363):

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
['rgb(103,0,31)','rgb(178,24,43)','rgb(214,96,77)','rgb(244,165,130)','rgb(253,219,199)','rgb(224,224,224)','rgb(186,186,186)','rgb(135,135,135)','rgb(77,77,77)','rgb(26,26,26)']
  .forEach(function(d,i){
    style.innerHTML += ".q" + i + " {fill:" + d + "; background-color: " + d + "}";
  });
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

var cal = new CalHeatMap();
cal.init({
  range: 10,
  start: new Date(2000, 0, 1, 1),
  data: "datas-hours.json"
});
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLPV39LYCMNBV1SFXv7X?p=preview).

Not sure I like either of these options, though.  You'd probably be better forking the repository, adding what you want and submitting a pull request.  Look down at line 3278 and swap out that color scale with your ordinal one.