# leaflet R, how to make appearance of clustered icon related to statistics of the children?

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

I'd like to customize appearance of clustered markers in Leaflet/Shiny application based on sum of an attribute of child markers.

It is similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600021/leaflet-for-r-how-to-customize-the-coloring-of-clusters), which makes icon color of clusters based on count of children.  What if I want to customize icon based on the sum of magnitude of earthquakes?

With pure javascript application, seems like I should be able to set custom property to individual marker, then access it from `iconCreateFunction`, as done in [this example](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/example/marker-clustering-custom.html).

But I am adding marker with `addCircleMarkers` and `addMarkers` from leaflet for R, and doesn't seem i can add arbitrary attribute to markers being generated.  Code below works but it doesn't if i uncomment two lines (`mag = ~mag` and `sum += markers[i].mag;`)

```
leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(
  # mag = ~mag,
  clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
  iconCreateFunction=JS("function (cluster) {    
    var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
    var sum = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    //  sum += markers[i].mag;
      sum += 1;
    }
    return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + sum + '</span></div>'});

  }")

  )
)
```

I thought about using `label=` option of `addMarkers`, and then parse it from Javascript.  But the markers accessed with `getAllChildMarkers()` on marker cluster in JS does not seem to have `label` property.

I also thought about passing a dataframe from R to leaflet(JS), somehow, maybe [like this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html), or [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html) ...?

Answer (score 6):

Found my answer.  Seems like I can put arbitrary property inside `options=` in `addMarker`:

```
leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(
  options = markerOptions(mag = ~mag),
  clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
  iconCreateFunction=JS("function (cluster) {    
    var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
    var sum = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      sum += Number(markers[i].options.mag);
//      sum += 1;
    }
    return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + sum + '</span></div>'});
  }")
  )
)
```

Comment: great, thanks much for sharing (+1 +1)! Could you indicate how to keep the default coloring and shape of the clusters? I tried adding back `,className: 'marker-cluster'` at the end of the JS function, but it seems we have to re-specify everything

Comment: you have to pass thing like below, two words, seems like.  `return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + sum + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster marker-cluster-medium', iconSize: new L.Point(40,40)});`  you need your logic to set if marker is large/small/medium, like the original code was doing

Comment: By original code I meant class definition of MarkerClusterGroup, _defaultIconCreateFunction(), found in here or somewhere nearby: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L820-L833

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks! I have a Question similar to yours. It's about clustering connecting linestrings of clusters of markers. Maybe someone here is also interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436142/aggregate-weighted-linestrings-for-clustered-markers-in-leaflet-in-r