# Linking javaScript code to CSS using a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up a photography website where when a user clicks on a photo they see the full size image. How would I link the CSS to the JavaScript? 
I cannot change the formatting of the original image. My thought would be to create a class in the JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Please help! Thank you!

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.image1').click(function() {
    var img= $(this).attr("src");
    var appear_image = "<div id='appear_image_div' onclick='closeImage()'></div>";
    appear_image = appear_image.concat("<img id='appear_image' src='"+img+"'/>");
    appear_image = appear_image.concat("<img id='close_image' onClick='closeImage()' src='close.png'/>");
    $('body').append(appear_image);

  });
});

function closeImage () {
  $('#appear_image_div').remove();
  $('#appear_image').remove();
  $('close_image').remove ();
}
```

```css
imagefull {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="item"><p class="gallerycaption">Venice, Italy<br />July 2017</p>
      <img src="media\photos_2\portraits\thumbnails\t_italy_1.jpg" alt="Venice, Italy, July 2017" class="image1"/></div>
```

[What I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIits.jpg)

Comment: `How would I link the CSS to the JavaScript?` ??  ... `My thought would be to create a class in the JavaScript` ??

Comment: what u want is called 'ModalBox' or 'popup'.      here.   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple demo, based on your code, of an overlay that opens when the image is clicked, and closes on click.

It uses event delegation ([`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) to identify all links of an `.image` item inside a container (`.images`). It opens an overlay, and uses [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to attach a one time event handler for closing the modal.

I also use a flag (`modalOpen`) to prevent opening more than one model, when an image is clicked.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var modalOpen = false;

  $('.images').on('click', '.image', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (modalOpen) return;

    modalOpen = true;

    var img = $(this).attr("src");
    var appear_image = $("<div id='appear_image_div' class='imagefull'></div>");
    appear_image.append("<img id='appear_image' src='" + img + "'/>");
    appear_image.append("<img id='close_image' src='close.png'/>");
    $('body').append(appear_image);

    $('#appear_image_div').click(function() {
      modalOpen = false;

      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.imagefull {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <div class="item">
    <p class="gallerycaption">Venice, Italy<br />July 2017</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Venice, Italy, July 2017" class="image" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p class="gallerycaption">Venice, Italy<br />July 2017</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/201/" alt="Venice, Italy, July 2017" class="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to build a real-time website, I suggest you to use something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp), No need to reinvent the wheel, there are plenty of the jquery plugins available for free and they look stunning too.

Comment: thanks, this is for a school project where we're not supposed to use said plugins. Those resources are awesome nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a class creation code sample in this question:  [How to dynamically create CSS class in JavaScript and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But other ways would be to use the `:active` CSS pseudo class, or an `onclick` HTML event, examples:

:active:

```
:active { *link to image file*; }
```

onclick:

```
*image_element*.onclick = function-for-image-view;
```

If you'd like to see other manipulation techniques, look at [this page](https://cloudinary.com/visualweb/display/IMMC/Image+Manipulation+Techniques).