# How to parse and change colors of a CSS Stylesheet on a live website via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Assuming the following **CSS stylesheet** is used on a live website. What is the best way to parse all the colors used on the stylesheet and change the values with new ones using JavaScript?

In this scenario, I can't create CSS classes to override the colors via plain CSS, so JavaScript is the only way to go. There is no manageable way to add or edit classes. Since they are dynamic and change on each new product release. And changes should happen only on Client side. With no need to store the overrides.

The goal is to re-theme an UI, overriding the existing color with a new color palette. Each old color will be converted into a new one. i.e #FFF -> #000 rgb(33,33,33) -> rgb(66,66,66)

```css
.my-classdas90das {
  color: #000000;
}

.other-classAd21 {
  background: rgba(255,255,255);
  border-color: #222222;
}

.a-class438I {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(44, 44, 44);
}
```

---

My first attempt was to loop and access the properties via:

```js
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You can always create classes in javascript and apply them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720483/3684265

Comment: appending a `<style>` tag after the shown one, any conflicting rules will cascade over what's show. thus, you can set the dynamic style tag's innerHTML with a full string of new rules, which is simpler than using the CSSOM, since you can use a template to generate the CSS string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create CSS class in JavaScript and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply)

Comment: In this scenario, there is no manageable way to add or edit classes. Since they are dynamic and change on each new product release. So the solutions above can't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the initial colors going into your stylesheet, you can utilize CSS [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and change them later in JavaScript with little difficulty. Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--color1', 'red');
  document.body.style.setProperty('--color2', 'pink');
  document.body.style.setProperty('--color3', 'green');
  document.body.style.setProperty('--color4', 'purple');

});
```

```css
:root {
  background: #eee;
  --color1: #555;
  --color2: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  --color3: #222222;
  --color4: rgba(44, 44, 44);
}

div,
button {
  margin: 1em;
}

.my-classdas90das {
  color: var(--color1);
}

.other-classAd21 {
  background: var(--color2);
  border: 2px solid var(--color3);
}

.a-class438I {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px var(--color4);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-classdas90das">
  my-classdas90das
</div>

<div class="other-classAd21">
  other-classAd21
</div>

<div class="a-class438I">
  a-class438I
</div>

<button id="change">Change Colors</button>
```

Comment: This approach loses IE support for what that's worth

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over those existing colors. And the stylesheet that I need to parse doesn't use custom properties. :/

Comment: @user3059415 I see. Do you need to change each individual color to another specific one, or are you overriding all colors to one new color? Can you elaborate more on what your outcome should be?

Comment: Surething. The goal is to re-theme an UI, overriding the existing color with a new color palette. Each old color will be converted into a new one. 

i.e
#FFF -> #000
rgb(33,33,33) -> rgb(66,66,66)

etc

Comment: You may want to consider using `document.documentElement` rather than `document.body` since it maps more directly to `:root`.