# Dynamically add attribute to css class instead of element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I recently came across this scenario where I wanted to add **css property to a class instead of an element**.

When i do this

```
    $('.class_with_css').css({display:'none'});
```

It would add the style `"display:none"` to all the elements that has the class `"class_with_css"` currently.
But in my case I had to apply `"class_with_css"` class to a new element after the above code was executed and want to retain this style addition. Is there a way to do this (something like add the property to the css class itself) without recalling the above function?

Eg.

1. two elements

```
    <div id=1 class="abc" ></div>
    <div id=2 class="abc" ></div>
```

2. Run the code

```
    $('.abc').css({display:'none'});
```

3. The element becomes:

```
    <div id=1 class="abc" style="display: none;"  ></div>
    <div id=2 class="abc" style="display: none;" ></div>
```

4. Now i add class abc to element like this

```
    <div id=3 class="abc" ></div>
```

Is there a way to make class "abc" to hold the style instead of element so that step 4's element also has `display:none`

Comment: No.  There is no logical state that knows that you need to apply an inline style to elements that get that class in the future.  Instead of adding the inline style change, you should add a css rule, modifying that class to include your display setting.

Comment: Otherwise, when you add the class, also set the inline style setting.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to achieve what you want directly. The way it usually is done by already having css class with desired changes/properties and applying that class instead of css property.

So, you will have for example:

```css
.hide {
    display: none
}
```

and add the class to elements:

```js
$('.abc').addClass('hide');
```

**UPDATE**
Another option if you really want to dynamically add css class, would be the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720483/735307)

Comment: Conversely, depending upon which state is more desired by default, it could also be flipped to `.abc:not(.visible) { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can inject style to your header.

**BUT REMEMBER** From that point on. You have to use `display: block;` to show it. Otherwise the default style will be `display: none;` until you refresh the page.

Inject() is injecting style to your header

Add() is adding "abc" class to your other divs

Showme() is adding "display: block" to ".abc"

Hideme() is adding "display: none" to ".abc"

```js
function Inject(){
  $('head').append('<style type="text/css">.abc {display: none;}</style>');
}
function Add() {
  $("#w").addClass("abc");
  $("#z").addClass("abc");
}
function Showme() {
 $(".abc").css("display","block");
}
function Hideme() {
 $(".abc").css("display","none");
}
```

```css
button {
border: 0;
padding: 1% 3%;
background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x" class="abc">x</div>
<div id="y" class="abc">y</div>
<div id="w">w</div>
<div id="z">z</div>
<p>First Click below and see how w and z are not hiding</p>
<button onclick="Inject()">Click to inject style to head</button>
<p>Second click below and add "abc" class to w and z.</p>
<button onclick="Add()">Click to add abc to w and z</button>
<p>Then click below to add style="display:block;"</p>
<button onclick="Showme()">Click to show anything with class "abc"</button>
<p>Then click below to add style="display:none;"</p>
<button onclick="Hideme()">Click to hide anything with class "abc"</button>
```

Comment: Can we just append the rule in existing `style` tag inside head, instead of creating new `style` tag in the head section.

Comment: @AamirSohailKmAs That would be .addClass() but he/she wanted to add a style to a class.

Comment: I'm asking about appending `<style type="text/css">.abc {display: none;}</style>` in head instead of appending `.abc {display: none;}` in already existing `style` tag.