# Dynamically creating CSS keyframe animation via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I know this is a messy way of trying to pull this off but perhaps it can be done...
What syntax is appropriate for assigning keyframe CSS animation dynamically through JavaScript?

```
var cue = document.createElement('div');
cue.setAttribute('id', 'cue');
cue.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'opacity:' + '0;'
);

var cueAnimation = document.createElement('style');
cueAnimation.type = 'text/css';
var rules = document.createTextNode('@-moz-keyframes pop {'+
    '0% { opacity:0; }'+
    '50% { opacity:1; }'+
    '100% { opacity:0; }'+
    '}');
cueAnimation.appendChild(rules);
cue.appendChild(cueAnimation);

appContainer.appendChild(cue);

...

cue.style.mozAnimationName = 'pop 2s'; //not sure how to trigger this...
```

note, I'm only aiming for Firefox in this demo, also content of the 'cue' div has been omitted for simplicity

Comment: Try adding `cueAnimation` not to `cue` but to the `head` element, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of these `moz` prefixes everywhere, Firefox supports unprefixed animation since years, so do every browsers. *(besides, it's `style.MozXXX`)*

Then, `style.animationName` should be the animation's name (yes), and your animation is called "`pop`", not "`pop 2s`".

`2s` would be a valid value for `style.animationDuration`:

```js
var cue = document.createElement('div');
cue.setAttribute('id', 'cue');
cue.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'opacity:' + '0;'
);
cue.textContent = "hello";

var cueAnimation = document.createElement('style');
cueAnimation.type = 'text/css';
var rules = document.createTextNode('@keyframes pop {'+
    '0% { opacity:0; }'+
    '50% { opacity:1; }'+
    '100% { opacity:0; }'+
    '}');
cueAnimation.appendChild(rules);
cue.appendChild(cueAnimation);

appContainer.appendChild(cue);

cue.style.animationName = 'pop';
cue.style.animationDuration = '2s';
```

```html
<div id="appContainer"></div>
```

`pop 2s` looks more like the shorthand `animation` property:

```js
var cue = document.createElement('div');
cue.setAttribute('id', 'cue');
cue.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'opacity:' + '0;'
);
cue.textContent = "hello";

var cueAnimation = document.createElement('style');
cueAnimation.type = 'text/css';
var rules = document.createTextNode('@keyframes pop {'+
    '0% { opacity:0; }'+
    '50% { opacity:1; }'+
    '100% { opacity:0; }'+
    '}');
cueAnimation.appendChild(rules);
cue.appendChild(cueAnimation);

appContainer.appendChild(cue);

cue.style.animation = 'pop 2s';
```

```html
<div id="appContainer"></div>
```

But I can't help to note that if you are on the way to write dynamic stylesheets, it makes very little sense to set your element's inline styles; rather set these styles inside your stylesheet too:

```js
var cue = document.createElement('div');
cue.setAttribute('id', 'cue');
cue.textContent = "hello";

var cueAnimation = document.createElement('style');
cueAnimation.type = 'text/css';
var rules = document.createTextNode( '' +
'#cue {' +
'  opacity: 0;'+
'  animation: pop 2s infinite;'+
'}' +
'@keyframes pop {'+
'  0% { opacity:0; }'+
'  50% { opacity:1; }'+
'  100% { opacity:0; }'+
'}');
cueAnimation.appendChild(rules);
cue.appendChild(cueAnimation);
appContainer.appendChild(cue);
```

```html
<div id="appContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much :)