# Multiples iterations of a CSS class for re-use multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic webpage which I'm trying to show progress/completion status of one background task by using CSS from [this Liquid bubble progress bar](https://codepen.io/junebug12851/pen/mJZNqN).

Further, I have multiple such background tasks and I want to show progress of each in the same html webpage by using another copy of that bubble progress bar.
Say like I want to have 5 such bubbles and each showing progress of 5 independent tasks, I guess I have to copy paste the CSS of 1 bubble and change from name x to y for 5 times and use the 5 new names accordingly. Which is not right way to do.

Is there a way where i can replicate it for T times with a new names using javascript or something or any easy methods?

Please could I get some help to make the right javascript code and the right function calls to achieve that. Thanks heaps in advance.

Below is the CSS code from the source.

```css
@import "nib"

@keyframes spin
  from
    transform rotate(0deg)
  to
    transform rotate(360deg)

 placeholder()
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder
    {block}
  :-moz-placeholder
    {block}
  ::-moz-placeholder
    {block}
  :-ms-input-placeholder
    {block}

text-glow()
  text-shadow 0 0 arguments

box-glow()
  box-shadow 0 0 arguments

// Page
page-font = sans-serif
page-background-color = darken(white, 90%)

progress-bubble($color, $amount)
  // Progress Bar
  progress-primary-color = $color
  progress-size = 250px
  progress-border-size = 5px
  progress-inner-border-size = 5px
  progress-inner-size = progress-size - (progress-border-size + progress-inner-border-size)
  progress-inner-border = progress-inner-border-size solid page-background-color

  progress-alpha = 50%
  progress-level-change-speed = 1s
  progress-swish-speed = 10s
  progress-percent-color = darken(progress-primary-color, 40%)

  progress-percent-glow = 10px darken(progress-percent-color, 25%)
  progress-box-glow = 20px darken(progress-percent-color, 25%)
  progress-liquid-glow = 20px darken(progress-percent-color, 5%)

  progress-glare-background = rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)
  progress-level = (100% - $amount)
  
  .progress
    +cache('.progress')
      position relative
      border-radius 50%

    +cache('.progress' + progress-size)
      width progress-size
      height progress-size
    
    +cache('.progress' + progress-border-size + " " + progress-primary-color)
      border progress-border-size solid progress-primary-color
    
    +cache('.progress' + progress-box-glow)
      box-glow progress-box-glow
    
    +cache('.progress' + progress-level-change-speed)
      transition all progress-level-change-speed ease
      
    .inner
      +cache('.progress .inner')
        position absolute
        overflow hidden
        z-index 2
        border-radius 50%
        
      +cache('.progress .inner' + progress-inner-size)
        width progress-inner-size
        height progress-inner-size

      +cache('.progress .inner' + progress-inner-border)
        border progress-inner-border
        
      +cache('.progress .inner' + progress-level-change-speed)
        transition all progress-level-change-speed ease

      .water
        +cache('.progress .inner .water')
          position absolute
          z-index 1
          width 200%
          height 200%
          left -50%
          border-radius 40%
          animation-iteration-count infinite
          animation-timing-function linear
          animation-name spin
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .water' + progress-level)
          top progress-level
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .water' + progress-primary-color + " " + progress-alph)
          background alpha(progress-primary-color, progress-alpha)
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .water' + progress-level-change-speed)
          transition all progress-level-change-speed ease
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .water' + progress-swish-speed)
          animation-duration progress-swish-speed
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .water' + progress-liquid-glow)
          box-glow progress-liquid-glow

      .glare
        +cache('.progress .inner .glare')
          position absolute
          top -120%
          left -120%
          z-index 5
          width 200%
          height 200%
          transform rotate(45deg)
          border-radius 50%
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .glare' + progress-glare-background)
          background-color progress-glare-background
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .glare' + progress-level-change-speed)
          transition all progress-level-change-speed ease

      .percent
        +cache('.progress .inner .percent')
          position absolute
          top 0
          left 0
          width 100%
          height 100%
          font-weight bold
          text-align center
          
        +cache('.progress .inner .percent' + progress-inner-size)
          line-height progress-inner-size
          font-size (progress-inner-size / 2.6px)
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .percent' + progress-percent-color)
          color progress-percent-color
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .percent' + progress-percent-glow)
          text-glow progress-percent-glow
        
        +cache('.progress .inner .percent' + progress-level-change-speed)
          transition all progress-level-change-speed ease

*
  box-sizing border-box

html, body
  height 100%

body
  background-color page-background-color
  font-family page-font
  font-size 15px
  color darken(white, 20%)

input[type="text"]
  background-color transparent
  margin-top 30px
  border 0
  border-bottom solid 1px lighten(blue, 50%)
  text-align center
  font-size 20px
  color lighten(rgb(50, 118, 237), 15%)
  text-glow 3px lighten(rgb(50, 118, 237), 15%)
  width 45px
  display inline-block
  
input:focus
  outline 0
  border-bottom dashed 1px lighten(red, 50%)

input::selection
  color page-background-color
  background-color lighten(lightblue, 30%)

+placeholder()
  color lighten(rgb(50, 118, 237), 35%)
  text-glow 3px lighten(rgb(50, 118, 237), 35%)

.wrapper
  display flex
  align-items center
  justify-content center
  flex-direction column
  height 100%

.green
  margin-top 15px
  progress-bubble(rgb(83, 252, 83), 75%)

.red
  margin-top 15px
  progress-bubble(rgb(237, 59, 59), 25%)

.orange
  margin-top 15px
  progress-bubble(rgb(240, 124, 62), 50%)

#copyright
  margin-top 25px
  background-color transparent
  font-size 14px
  color darken(white, 30%)
  text-align center
  
  div
    margin-bottom 10px
  
  a
  a:link
    color gray
    text-decoration none
    border-bottom 1px solid gray
    padding-bottom 2px

  a:active
    color darken(white, 30%)
  
  a:hover
    color darken(white, 30%)
    border-bottom 1px solid darken(white, 30%)
    padding-bottom 4px

.instructions
  display inline-block
  margin 5px 0
  font-size 16px
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, which seems to be a common technique, is to create new STYLE tags and append them into the BODY tag.

For example - see [Create classes using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply)

With that method, you could build up whatever innerHTML you wanted to construct a complete class, or set of classes, using variables where necessary.

Here's a very simple idea of how that works:

```js
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    // returns a random number between min and max, inclusive
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function createBoxes() {
  let bdy = document.body;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let d = document.createElement("div");
    d.className = "div" + i;
    bdy.appendChild(d);
  }
  let s = document.createElement("style");
  s.type = "text/css";
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let r = getRandomNumber(0, 255);
    let g = getRandomNumber(0, 255);
    let b = getRandomNumber(0, 255);
    s.innerHTML += "\n.div" + i + "{background-color:rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "); height:100px; width:100px;}\n";
    bdy.appendChild(s);
  }
}
// for testing purposes only
window.onload = createBoxes;
```

Answer (score 2):

this should help you to get the idea. what I did is mapped the bubble with input using a custom `attribute` and then binding the click and change events using the custom attribute `groupid`

```js
var colorInc = 100 / 3;

$(function() {
  $(".percent-box").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $(this).select();
    });
  })


  $(".percent-box").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      var groupId = $(this).attr('group'); // get the group id to correctly target the liquid bubble
      if (val <= 100 &&
        val >= 0) {}
      if (val != "" &&
        !isNaN(val) &&
        val <= 100 &&
        val >= 0) {
        //console.log(val);
        var valOrig = val;
        val = 100 - val;
        if (valOrig == 0) {
          $("[group=" + groupId + "] .percent-box").val(0);
          $("[group=" + groupId + "] .progress .percent").text(0 + "%");
        } else $("[group=" + groupId + "] .progress .percent").text(valOrig + "%");

        $("[group=" + groupId + "]  .progress").parent().removeClass();
        $("[group=" + groupId + "] .progress .water").css("top", val + "%");

        if (valOrig < colorInc * 1)
          $("[group=" + groupId + "] .progress").parent().addClass("red");
        else if (valOrig < colorInc * 2)
          $("[group=" + groupId + "]  .progress").parent().addClass("orange");
        else
          $("[group=" + groupId + "]  .progress").parent().addClass("green");
      } else {
        $("[group=" + groupId + "] .progress").parent().removeClass();
        $("[group=" + groupId + "] .progress").parent().addClass("green");
        $("[group=" + groupId + "] .progress .water").css("top", 100 - 67 + "%");
        $("[group=" + groupId + "] .progress .percent").text(67 + "%");
        $("[group=" + groupId + "].percent-box").val($("[group=" + groupId + "].percent-box").attr('placeholder'));
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ccc;
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #8080ff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #518bf0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #518bf0;
  width: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #ff8080;
}

input::-moz-selection {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  background-color: #c6e4ee;
}

input::selection {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  background-color: #c6e4ee;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #7aa6f3;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #7aa6f3;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #7aa6f3;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #7aa6f3;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #7aa6f3;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #7aa6f3;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #7aa6f3;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #7aa6f3;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -o-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -o-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -o-box-orient: vertical;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.green {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.green .progress,
.red .progress,
.orange .progress {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.green .progress,
.red .progress,
.orange .progress {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.green .progress {
  border: 5px solid #53fc53;
}

.green .progress {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #029502;
}

.green .progress,
.red .progress,
.orange .progress {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.green .progress .inner,
.red .progress .inner,
.orange .progress .inner {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.green .progress .inner,
.red .progress .inner,
.orange .progress .inner {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
}

.green .progress .inner,
.red .progress .inner,
.orange .progress .inner {
  border: 5px solid #1a1a1a;
}

.green .progress .inner,
.red .progress .inner,
.orange .progress .inner {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.green .progress .inner .water,
.red .progress .inner .water,
.orange .progress .inner .water {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  left: -50%;
  border-radius: 40%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  animation-name: spin;
}

.green .progress .inner .water {
  top: 25%;
}

.green .progress .inner .water {
  background: rgba(83, 252, 83, 0.5);
}

.green .progress .inner .water,
.red .progress .inner .water,
.orange .progress .inner .water {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.green .progress .inner .water,
.red .progress .inner .water,
.orange .progress .inner .water {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.green .progress .inner .water {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #03bc03;
}

.green .progress .inner .glare,
.red .progress .inner .glare,
.orange .progress .inner .glare {
  position: absolute;
  top: -120%;
  left: -120%;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.green .progress .inner .glare,
.red .progress .inner .glare,
.orange .progress .inner .glare {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.green .progress .inner .glare,
.red .progress .inner .glare,
.orange .progress .inner .glare {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.green .progress .inner .percent,
.red .progress .inner .percent,
.orange .progress .inner .percent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.green .progress .inner .percent,
.red .progress .inner .percent,
.orange .progress .inner .percent {
  line-height: 240px;
  font-size: 92.3076923076923px;
}

.green .progress .inner .percent {
  color: #03c603;
}

.green .progress .inner .percent {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #029502;
}

.green .progress .inner .percent,
.red .progress .inner .percent,
.orange .progress .inner .percent {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.red {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.red .progress {
  border: 5px solid #ed3b3b;
}

.red .progress {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #7a0b0b;
}

.red .progress .inner .water {
  top: 75%;
}

.red .progress .inner .water {
  background: rgba(237, 59, 59, 0.5);
}

.red .progress .inner .water {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #9b0e0e;
}

.red .progress .inner .percent {
  color: #a30f0f;
}

.red .progress .inner .percent {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #7a0b0b;
}

.orange {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.orange .progress {
  border: 5px solid #f07c3e;
}

.orange .progress {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #7e320a;
}

.orange .progress .inner .water {
  top: 50%;
}

.orange .progress .inner .water {
  background: rgba(240, 124, 62, 0.5);
}

.orange .progress .inner .water {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #a0400c;
}

.orange .progress .inner .percent {
  color: #a8430d;
}

.orange .progress .inner .percent {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #7e320a;
}

#copyright {
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  text-align: center;
}

#copyright div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#copyright a,
#copyright a:link {
  color: #808080;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#copyright a:active {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

#copyright a:hover {
  color: #b3b3b3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.instructions {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="instructions">The progress bubble below can transition between red, orange, and green depending on the current percentage.</span>
<span class="instructions">Go ahead and try it out by using the text box below.</span>

<div class="green" group="1">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="percent"><span>67</span>%</div>
      <div class="water"></div>
      <div class="glare"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<span>Enter Percentage: <input type="text" group="1" placeholder="67" class = 'percent-box' id="percent-box1">%</span>

<div class="green" group="2">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="percent"><span>67</span>%</div>
      <div class="water"></div>
      <div class="glare"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span>Enter Percentage: <input type="text" group="2" placeholder="67" class = 'percent-box' id="percent-box2">%</span>
<div class="green" group="3">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="percent"><span>67</span>%</div>
      <div class="water"></div>
      <div class="glare"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span>Enter Percentage: <input type="text" group="3" placeholder="67" class = 'percent-box' id="percent-box3">%</span>
```