# why creating a style element doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a CSS class in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393162/creating-a-css-class-in-jquery)

```
$("< style>span{color:red}< /style>");


jQuery < span>jQuery< /span> jQuery
```

Comment: Voting to close. Please add more details and then add a comment

Comment: Why do you enclose it in $(), it's unnecessary.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393162/creating-a-css-class-in-jquery

Comment: You should read a jQuery tutorial first: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heh, interesting idea.

This works if you insert the element into the DOM:

```
 $('head').append($("<style>span{color:red}</style>"));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6W7Wb/1/)

Dynamically fiddling with CSS usually has *some* side effects, but this should okay: It works fine even in IE6.

Comment: He hasn't actually appended it to the DOM though. If that's what he's trying to do at any rate

Comment: Just a tip for the future: If you are going to be chaining more commands, append gives you the item you are appending to, while appendTo gives you back the item you are appending.  In this case, there's not much value, but I like to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

`$("<style>span{color:red}</style>").appendTo('head');` ?

Comment: No need for the `$('head')` part, just use: `.appendTo('head');`

Comment: Oops, lol. I typed that pretty fast.