# Alter CSS rule definition using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say you want to change the width of many elements, to simulate a table, for example.  I realize you could do this:

```
$(".class").css('width', '421px');
```

This alters the inline `style='width: 421px;'` attribute *for each element*.  Now, what I'd LIKE to do: is change the actual CSS rule definition:

```
.class {
    width: 375px;  ==[change to]==> 421px;
}
```

When it comes to 100's if not 1000's of nested `<ul>` and `<li>` that need to be changed, it seems like this would be better for performance than trying to let jQuery do the work through the `.css()` method.

I've found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393162/creating-a-css-class-in-jquery) - this IS what I'm trying to do:

```
var style = $('<style>.class { width: 421px; }</style>')
$('html > head').append(style);
```

I'm NOT trying to swap classes (`$el.removeClass().addClass()`), because I can't have a class for EVERY optimal width (379px, 387px, 402px..).

I could create a `<style>` element and dynamically set the width, however I'm thinking there's a better way.

Comment: I really think you should write two classes in your CSS, and add/remove the appropriate ones when needed. You should not mess with your stylesheet in JS, it will quickly become unmaintainable.

Comment: @kapa, this has its limits, because all the CSS has to be defined in advance.  You could not, for example, highlight arbitrary nth-child elements: `#root>div:nth-child('+Nth+') { background: red; }`

Answer (score 1):

**document.styleSheets[0].addRule** works in Chrome, 'not a function' in FF

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to include an empty style block in the header:

```
<style id="custom-styles"></style>
```

And then manipulate that with something like this:

```
$('#custom-styles').text('h1 { background: red }')
```

I've tested this appears to work in current version of Chrome (well, Chromium - 63.0) and Firefox (57.0.4).