# Change CSS properties of non-existing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the dimensions of a set of elements that are not created yet. They will be created by a JavaScript script that I don't have access to. JQuery's *css()* function would apply the changes only on existing items, while I want the code to work like if I had set CSS properties in a CSS file.

Can anyone help me do it?

Comment: Do those elements have something identifiable, like a class? If so, you could define rules directly in CSS.

Comment: What's the problem of setting these properties in CSS?

Comment: @pimvdb The CSS properties of the element must be set based on the user action.

Comment: @VisioN  The elements I want to edit do have a class.

Comment: if the user interaction is event based after the new elements are inserted, situation is straightforard. Need to provide a lot more information as to what you expect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to dynamically create a style element:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .redbold{ color:#f00; font-weight:bold;} </style>").appendTo("head")
$("<div/>").addClass("redbold").appendTo("body");
```

Taken from here: [Create a CSS rule / class with jQuery at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime).

Here's a possible IE alternative (see [Creating a CSS class in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393162/creating-a-css-class-in-jquery)):

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('body', 'background: green', -1);
```

For reference, see the documentation for [addRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358796%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: can't insert css rules directly into head tag without a style tag. Older IE versions don't do well with appended style tags either

Comment: @charlietfl - I messed up when pasting in the code (new to SO).  Also added a possible alternative for IE.