# How to make jQuery css affect upcoming elements

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to make jQuery (or any javascript) change the CSS scheme instead of just apply the style to the current elements matching the descriptor?

Suppose I have this on my css `.bla{ width: 200px;}`. if I run `$('.bla').css('width', 300);` then jQuery will only apply this to the existing elements.

What I want is a way to make the new width be the rule also for new .bla elements. To make it so that, if I keep adding .bla elements, then they will be 300 width.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is possible to programmatically edit that existing rule. Alternatively, you could create a new style sheet (also programmatically) which would override that rule, e.g. via `body .bla { width: 300px }`. The [CSSOM standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/) defines APIs which provide this functionality.

Comment: How do you add new .bla elements?

Comment: You really should consider keeping it within the main style sheet. So, for example, a `.wide .bla {width: 300px;}` style, then add .wide to the parent. That'll keep everything together.

Comment: @JamesS, it will be dynamically calculated, considering $('html').width() and recalculated on resize event.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, it's raw html comming through a $.get call. I'm using $('#result').append() to insert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var style = $('<style>body { background: green; }</style>')
$('html > head').append(style);
```

This is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393162/creating-a-css-class-in-jquery) link

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$('.bla').css('width', 300);` it is due to a condition in your page.

If you store this condition in a variable, then every time you add the new matching elements you can check to see if they need to be modified

```
var someCondition=false;

/* later in code*/
$('.bla').css('width', 300);
someCondition=true;

/* then when add elements*/

var newBla=$('<div class="bla">')
if( someConditon){
  newBla.css('width', 300);
}
```

If you did this with CSS and applied class instead you could use :

```
toggleClass( 'bla_300_class', someCondition); /* second arument is boolean to add or remove*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="style">
<style>.bla{ width: 200px;}</style>
</div>
<div id="divs"></div>

</div>
<button id="adddiv">Add div</button>
<button id="changeWidth">Click To Change Width</button>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#adddiv").click(function(){
$("#divs").append('<div class="bla" style="border:1px solid red;height:20px;margin:2px;">');
});
$("#changeWidth").click(function(){
$(".style").html("<style>.bla{width:300px;}</style>")
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

You can test the script online here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s92XU/)