# Webkit scrollbar dynamic styling

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, scrollbar

I'm currently styling the scrollbar using Webkit's ::-webkit-scrollbar CSS properties and would like to change these properties on a mousemove event. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get to the scrollbar's CSS dynamically.

Is it possible to style the webkit scrollbar dynamically, through javascript (possibly using jQuery)?

Comment: May be this can help.. Insert style dynamically into the body on your mouse move event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime

Comment: For more current readers - make sure if you are removing the scrollbar using ::-webkit-scrollbar, this works for Chromium browsers but make sure you also apply `scrollbar-width: 0` to either the body or HTML tags (I found I had to do it on the HTML tag). This is easily done using JS to add inline styling with the .style attribute for the body or HTML element.

Answer (score 11):

There is a nice workaround for this problem, you can add multiple css classes with diffident styles for the scrollbar, and then change the classes dynamically with Javascript.

Example:

```
.red::-webkit-scrollbar  { ... }
.blue::-webkit-scrollbar { ... }
```

A button that toggles between the classes `red` and `blue`:

```
$("#changecss").on("click", function(){
    $(".red,.blue").toggleClass("red").toggleClass("blue");
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/wZwJz/18/

Comment: I had an issue with force-redraw, and I found it in your fiddle. If anyone will look for it, the hack is to update value of `overflow` and get the height of the body.

`document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';`
`document.body.offsetHeight;`
`document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it.

You need to include dynamically css style rule into stylesheet.
And then to change it.

You can do it by [this plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/rule/)

If you don't need to use jQuery - you can do it by pure Javascript:
[link 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/Overview.html)
[link 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule).
But there is cross-browser problems.

Also see [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Comment: thanks, I don't like it and I won't use it, but this is indeed the only solution at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change a scrollbar properties when mouse is over it. You can do it with CSS, here an example http://jsfiddle.net/olgis/7Lg2R/ (sorry for ugly colorset).

If you want to change scrollbar colour if the mouse is over a container then look at this post [Style webkit scrollbar on certain state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632410/style-webkit-scrollbar-on-certain-state) . There are described several ways of doing it, with and  without JavaScript.

REMARK: I do not know for which reason none of those example (with CSS neither JavaScript) do NOT work in my Firefox 11 for Mint, but all of them works perfectly in Chrome 18.0.1025.151.

Answer (score 2):

i created page with four tabs each different color set as well as scroll bar
however this only worked by giving class to body tag

```
body.greenbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 10px;
}
body.greenbody::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-color:rgb(0,50,0);
}
body.greenbody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-image:url("../assets/ScrollGreen.png"); 
}
```

/

```
body.bluebody::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 10px;
}
body.bluebody::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-color:rgb(0,0,50);
}
body.bluebody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-image:url("../assets/ScrollBlue.png"); 
}
```

html

```
<body id="body" class="greenbody" bgcolor="#202020">
```

javascript for each tab button(only scroll bar section shown here)

```
document.getElementById("body").className="greenody";
.........other function().... 
document.getElementById("body").className="bluebody";
```

[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhAC3.jpg)  [GreenScrollBar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbZ8C.png)
[ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sioi1.jpg)  [BlueScrollBar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqyq5.png)

Comment: Is that all your HTML? You might want to look into reading some more of the HTML and CSS basics, as it looks like you're not familiar with basic CSS to apply fixed heights and scroll the content within other elements. Ultimately, there's a lot of unasked questions within this question.

Comment: Well , I'm really very new to this.Just doing it as "time-pass". And I didn't had subject to work on... so i just worked out a document on myself.And made it almost compatible to mobile(tested on mine) and tabs(tested chrome dev tools).

Comment: [Rajnoor Brar](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mFVqZMyJbU1OrpB3oZDAi0vG8pNzDnjz) Well,This is the link to whole web(.zip) .Check it out. Ther's more than meets the eye. @SEoF

Answer (score 1):

For this you should replace the scrollbar altogether.

It's just a matter of [picking whichever one gives you the easiest API](http://slodive.com/web-development/jquery-scroll/).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! But unfortunately I'm personally not wanting to use jQuery.

Comment: @Sebas the original question sais `"possibly using jQuery"`

Answer (score 1):

You can style scrollbars with CSS3, these generally only work for internal scrollbars and not the actual browser main scrollbar. You can also add the MOZ attribute to the following.

```
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment  {
            display: none;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
            background-color: #3b3b3b;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
            background: #666 url(scrollbar_thumb_bg.png) no-repeat center;
        }
```

Demo: http://geryit.com/lib/custom-css3-scrollbars

Download Source: http://geryit.com/lib/custom-css3-scrollbars/custom-css3-scrollbars.zip

Answer (score 1):

you can make a `<style>` tag with `id="scrollbar_style"` and then add css inside it dynamicly like this :

```
document.getElementById('scrollbar_style').innerHTML = '::-webkit-scrollbar{width:15px;}';
```

just remember that using **innerHTML** on an element **WILL NOT JUST ADD** your new code, it **WILL ALSO DELETE** whatever was inside that element.

problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a function in JavaScript with your own css.

```
function overFlow(el) {
   el.style.cssText = "overflow: auto;";
}
```

using in html:

```
<style>
::-webkit-scrollbar{display = none;}
</style>

<div id="overFlow" onclick="overFlow(this);">Something</div>
```

More Info: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/