# change the colour of scrollbar when hover on a specific div

Tags: javascript, css

I m trying to change the colour of the scrollbar of a div whenever I hover on the div.How could I do it ? Is there any way of doing it without giving the id of the div ? what I tried so far is ;

```
div:hover {

   ::-webkit-scrollbar{color:black}

}
```

and

```
div:hover + ::-webkit-scrollbar{

  color: black;  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style webkit scrollbar on certain state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632410/style-webkit-scrollbar-on-certain-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: black;
}
```