# How to increase width of the scroll bar when user hover's on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Hi I am having issue with my  custom scroll

**requirement :**  when ever user hovers on to a div then only scroll bar has to be shown and when user hover's on scroll bar then the scroll bar width has to increase from 5px to 15px.

**what i did :**  i created custom scroll bar and implemented hover on div and but im facing issue when user hover on scrollbar i unable to increase it size.

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px;
  width: 15px;
}

 *::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {

  width: 15px;
}





 *:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    
}
```

below is my code

**.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table">
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
      Hello<br />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**css code :**

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  border: 1px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #ebf0f5;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  width: 15px;
}

.table {
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.55);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

app url :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-9mbus1?file=styles.css

instead of increased width and applying color it is just applying color

[image]

Comment: Which browser (and its version) are you using?

Comment: @AsifSharifShahid Chrome ver 99.0

Comment: I hope this will help you. [https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar-width/](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar-width/)

Comment: tried it notworking

Comment: Check its browser support section.

Comment: What do you mean by "when ever user logs on to a div"? What user action on the div are you talking about?

Comment: @theHutt hover's on to div and u can the check the stack blitz which i created

Comment: Is it ok to use Javascript? CSS only solution seems not possible, because `::-webkit-scrollbar` doesn't respect `:hover` pseudo class.

Comment: Yeah I mean react I'm using @theHutt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try This:-

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        let ele = document.getElementById('element');
        let distance = ele.offsetLeft + ele.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
        distance < 15 && distance > -15 ? ele.classList.add('more-width') : ele.classList.remove('more-width');
    });
```

```css
#element {
     position: relative;
     left: 150px;
     top: 150px;
     width: 200px;
     max-height: 200px;
     background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.55);
     overflow: auto;
}
 #element::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     background: #888;
}
 #element::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 5px;
}
 #element.more-width::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking the same! But you'll have to do more handling. If I move cursor outside the red box above the scrollbar the scrollbar still expands. You need to attach the event to the element and not document. Also need to handle mouseout or mouseleave event to remove the `more-width` class.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set it to 15px in the first place.

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I already applied  https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-9mbus1?file=styles.css

Comment: @Madpop It seems to work for me, I'm on mobile at the moment though.

Comment: @Madpop You copied it, but didn't delete the one directly in front of it. You have two CSS statements of "*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {". Delete the second one.

Comment: i tried and updated the code too https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-9mbus1?file=styles.css and it is not working

Comment: @Madpop Maybe try something here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19171215/12359120 I'm on my phone right now so I'm sorry that I can't help to the fullest extent.

Answer (score 0):

The `::-webkit-scrollbar` element is [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) (Not compatible with Firefox).

In any case it looks like it can't be done with CSS alone.

Consequently you may be better off looking at a re-write.

Found a possible approach [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-scrollbar-on-hover-ps471) as well as a [blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/build-on-hover-custom-scrollbar-in-react-d846194a7ea4) and a [github-link](https://github.com/hkurra/react-on-hover-scrollbar) to (hopefully) compensate for not including the code inline!