# Change colour of scrollbar at anchor point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating an E-portfolio that would be viewed on either Chrome or Safari. I've already tried using the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
            var scroll_pos = 0;
            $(document).scroll(function() { 
                scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
                if(scroll_pos < 2251) {
                    $("body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb").css('background-color', '#1E791E');
                } else {
                    $("body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb").css('background-color', '#FF7A00');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried styling ::-webkit-scrollbar-track and ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb directly instead of using the body prefix?

Comment: Yeah, without the body prefix it doesn't change the ordinary css at all. Thanks though

Comment: If you want a "cross-browser" custom scrollbar, you should maybe use this jQuery plugin: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: Basically, "How to change CSS at anchor point" ? You can google it very easily.

Answer (score 0):

The `.css()` method applies CSS **properties** to an element.

`::webkit-scrollbar-*` are CSS **selectors** that select pseudo-elements.
jQuery does not have any methods that interact with pseudo-elements.

Instead, you can create a class with the ::webkit-scrollbar pseudo-elements and use jQuery to add that class when you want to make your adjustment.

**CSS**

```
.test::-webkit-scrollbar {
       // your code here
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('body').addClass('test');
```

Also, found this JSFiddle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15603340/3739658)

http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/wZwJz/18/

Which could be useful for you!

**Solution #2: JQuery Plugin**

[jScrollPane - cross browser styleable scrollbars with jQuery and CSS](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)