# How to remove todays button from datepicker in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new in jquery. I want to remove todays button from datepicker in Jquery. How to do that? I am using Jquery ui 1.8.10.

Regards,
Girish

Comment: do you mean to remove it or to disable today's date from being selected?

Comment: yes i want to remove it completely.

Comment: I want to hide the today button from calendaer in datepicker.

Answer (score 28):

use this style in your css file

```
button.ui-datepicker-current { display: none; }
```

Comment: this is what i exactly was looking.
it disables the today button at still shows the panel with the X close button.

Answer (score 17):

I have this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "c-150:c+30",
        showButtonPanel:true,
        closeText:'Clear',
        beforeShow: function( input ) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();
                var clearButton = $(input ).datepicker( "widget" ).find( ".ui-datepicker-close" );
                clearButton.unbind("click").bind("click",function(){$.datepicker._clearDate( input );});
            }, 1 );
        }
}).attr("readonly", true);
```

the line :

```
$(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();
```

hide the today button

Comment: Great solution! This is better to those above.

Comment: Excellent solution.  The CSS solutions will remove it from all the date pickers.  Yours is limited to whatever selector you use.

Answer (score 14):

### [Working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/KK7H4/)

Read more on [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-showButtonPanel)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    "showButtonPanel":  false
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: You could post at least a little snippet of how you did it, it is not that complicated :).

Comment: That's nice. I can't access jsFiddle in the last 2 hours for unknown reasons, thus cannot award you a +1. Please always post a little snippet of what you have done, links are not for eternity :). jsFiddles are actually just an addition to your answer, to demonstrate how your solution works.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: What if I want to display the "Done" button ?

Answer (score 5):

you can hide it with css

```
button.ui-datepicker-current { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the button by  setting the `showButtonPanel` to false, but this will remove all buttons. If you want to just remove the `Today` button, then you can use this snippet of code:

```
$('<style type="text/css"> .ui-datepicker-current { display: none; } </style>').appendTo("head");
```

This will append a style rule to your page that will set the `Today` button to have a display of none thereby hiding the button.

Credit to goes to [JQuery DatePicker Tweaks](http://www.billbblog.com/Programming/11/JQuery-DatePicker) and [jquery create css rule / class @ runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime) for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use showButtonPanel option to remove or show the buttons in datepicker

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the today button add this line to like below:

```
$('#sandbox-datepicker').datepicker({
        todayBtn: false 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.timecalender').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                timeFormat: 'H:mm',
                buttonText: 'Select Date',
                showsTime: true,
                timeOnly: true,
            }).focus(function () {
                $(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more block. Check only `$("#sameName").focus();`

```
$( "#sameName" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'M yy',
  showButtonPanel: true,
  maxDate : 0 });

$("#sameName").focus(function () {        
    $(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();       
});
```

Answer (score -1):

check this out [minDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate)
you can implement it like this

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) });
```

just put today's date as the minDate then it will exclude today's date

Comment: I want to hide the today button from calendaer in datepicker.

Answer (score -1):

Here an example:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#DATETIME_START").Zebra_DatePicker({
      format: "Y-m-d H:i:s",
      show_select_today: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

this worked for me
Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and, after a day of research, I came up with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/konstantc/4jkef3a1/

```js
// *** (month and year only) ***
$(function() { 
  $('#datepicker1').datepicker( {
    yearRange: "c-100:c",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText:'Select',
    currentText: 'This year',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy (M y) (mm/y)', new Date(year, month, 1)));
    }
  }).focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom",
      of: $(this)
    });
  }).attr("readonly", false);
});
// --------------------------------



// *** (year only) ***
$(function() { 
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker( {
    yearRange: "c-100:c",
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText:'Select',
    currentText: 'This year',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', new Date(year, 1, 1)));
    }
  }).focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-month").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-prev").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-next").hide();
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom",
      of: $(this)
    });
  }).attr("readonly", false);
});
// --------------------------------



// *** (year only, no controls) ***
$(function() { 
  $('#datepicker3').datepicker( {
    dateFormat: "yy",
    yearRange: "c-100:c",
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    closeText:'Select',
    currentText: 'This year',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', new Date(year, 1, 1)));
    },
    onChangeMonthYear : function () {
      $(this).datepicker( "hide" );
    }
  }).focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-month").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-prev").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-next").hide();
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom",
      of: $(this)
    });
  }).attr("readonly", false);
});
// --------------------------------
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<div class="container">

  <h2 class="font-weight-light text-lg-left mt-4 mb-0"><b>jQuery UI Datepicker</b> custom select</h2>

  <hr class="mt-2 mb-3">
  <div class="row text-lg-left">
    <div class="col-12">

      <form>

        <div class="form-label-group">
        <label for="datepicker1">(month and year only : <code>id="datepicker1"</code> )</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" 
                 placeholder="(month and year only)" />
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-label-group">
        <label for="datepicker2">(year only : <code>input id="datepicker2"</code> )</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2" 
                 placeholder="(year only)" />
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-label-group">
        <label for="datepicker3">(year only, no controls : <code>input id="datepicker3"</code> )</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker3" 
                 placeholder="(year only, no controls)" />
        </div>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I know this question is pretty old but I thought that my solution can be of use to others that encounter this problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

you can select the appropriate date format

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

if you do not want you can remove dd from above
[This](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) might help you !!

Comment: also have a look over here http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat