# jQuery hide future matched element

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='my_class'></div>
<div class='my_class'></div>
<div class='my_class'></div>
<div class='my_class'></div>

jQuery('.my_class').hide();
jQuery('.some_other_class').live('click', function(){
// some other stuff that puts in another div with class 'my_class'
});
```

With this script, the first 4 divs will be hidden on load.  However, when I click whatever, the new div will not be.  How do I make it so that all future elements matching 'my_class' are automatically hidden as well?

*EDIT*

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime):

`$("<style type='text/css'> .redbold{ color:#f00; font-weight:bold;}

</style>").appendTo("head");
$("<div/>").addClass("redbold").text("SOME NEWTEXT").appendTo("body");`

This is more along the lines of what I would use.  Much dryer.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using CSS display:none for that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery('.my_class').live('hide');

**UPDATE:** Could you just use CSS code to set display: none; for all my_class elements?

Comment: No, sorry. I remembered that this should work but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: This won't work.  `.live()` binds an event handler to handle events on future elements.  It won't execute an effect on a future element which is what we're after here.

Comment: I could, I just don't want to tangle CSS into this as well.

Comment: Apparently, there is no way to delegate hide, so this wins by "dry"est.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'd want to ensure you've hidden the new element before it's rendered on your page:

```
jQuery('.my_class').hide();
jQuery('.some_other_class').live('click', function(){
   var myDiv = $('<div />', { "class": "my_class" }).hide().insertAfter('div.my_class:last');
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep this as dry as possible. I don't want to put that line in the 3 other scripts that also effect this page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do what you're after automatically, but you could try something like this:

```
jQuery('.some_other_class').live('click', function(){
    var myClassIsVisible = $(.my_class).is(':visible');
    var newDiv = // create new div with class 'my_class'
    newDiv.toggle(myClassIsVisible);
    // insert newDiv into the DOM
});
```

This would create the new `div` in the same state as the existing ones.