# How can I create alike css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dynamically create CSS class in JavaScript and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply)

I want to create css classes depending upon what user has specified a width in a textfield. I know I can do it using inline styles, but I want to avoid it as there are many properties to be taken care of. In this question "width" is just an example.

For eg: if user specifies width as "20" then I want -

```
.w20 {width:20px}
```

if user specifies 21 then I want

```
.w21 {width:21px}
```

and so on...

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/qGmsP/)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.stylesheets` to add css rules dynamically directly to your stylesheets.

```
styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
// check for undefined could make sense here
styleSheet.addRule(selector, style);
```

[insertRule Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)
[addRule Doc](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuucnct.php)

or create a new style-element

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.class { rules }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `document.stylesheets` to add css dynamically to your stylesheets.

```
styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
styleSheet.addRule(selector, style);
```

You could also use inline styles (id recommend this approach).

You can change the width of an element using JavaScript like this.

```
elem.style.width = "100px";
```

And using jQuery

```
$("#selector").css("width", "100px");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I knew the inline method and I have mentioned in question that I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime) to lean how to add css rules in runtime.

My opinion: with best software design, you will never need to do that.