# Create & Delete classes?

Tags: jquery, css, class, jquery-animate, css-transitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery create CSS rule / class @ runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime)

Is it possible to create & delete css classes with jQuery?

Please note I'm not talking about `addClass` and `removeClass`.  I actually want to write a new class and delete old classes with jQuery.

The reason I ask is because I have a ton of animations that I'm trying to convert to CSS3 transitions.  It gets a little hairy because the initial `height` I set is dynamic, so I'm currently trying to change the classes from a class without transitions to one with transitions.

The problem is that CSS is so much faster than jQuery that even though I set the CSS setting first and then switch the classes, the new CSS setting is actually applied *after* the classes are switched (love transitions for that).

So, I'd like to dynamically create classes & add them then remove them & delete them.

If this isn't possible, does anyone know how to get around my dynamic CSS setting problem?

Comment: some particular example would help

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That question doesn't cover deleting classes at runtime

Comment: @Joe, true, even though Andras Vass's answer mentions a way. Having the `<style>` elements expose `id` attributes and using these attributes to match them later can also solve this problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi maybe, but in my case, that would mean adding a class for each pixel.  no thank-you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new element to the html document:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .myclass{ color:#000; border:1px solid #000;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

But I don't think it is possible to directly attach it to an external css-file.

Comment: that's great!  is it possible to delete it?

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy It is not directly possible to delete a class from the `<style>`-tag, but if you really need it you can write a custom plugin that parses through the content of the tag and then delete parts.

Comment: would you mind adding that knowledge to ur a for check?  thank-you!