# Update element CSS from JSON

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create the JSON object before updating the CSS of the element, but the CSS doesn't get updated for the element.

My code:

```
var style = $.parseJSON("{\""  + attrName +  "\":\""  + $(this).val() +  "\"}");                                
elContainer.css(style);
```

Comment: There are too many closed quotes, that javascript line will give you a few syntax errors.

Comment: @Tallmaris: Well, it will give syntax errors, but not because of too many closed quotes. The syntax errors would come from the lack of string concatenators (`+`), right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant... I was in a bit of a hurry, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you making a JSON string and then parsing it, instead of just making a JS object?

This is what you should be doing, unless I'm misunderstanding:

```
var style = {};
style[attrName] = $(this).val();
eleContainer.css(style);
```

Or if you're truly just setting one CSS attribute, you could do as @Nick suggested, like this:

```
eleContainer.css(attrName, $(this).val());
```

BTW, if that's your actual code, you would probably be getting errors since you're missing the `+` concatenator.

---

**UPDATE:**

`.css()` is a one-time setting for the set of matched elements. It does not create a permanent CSS rule that applies to elements that don't yet exist.

If you want to actually create a CSS rule instead of applying certain CSS styles to a set of specific elements, then you could dynamically create a `<style>` tag:

```
$("<style> .container { "+ attrName +": '"+ $(this).val() +"'; } </style>")
    .appendTo('body');
```

See also: [Create a CSS rule / class with jQuery at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1212500/259457)

Comment: it didn't work for dynamically added elements
but works fine for the static elements

Answer (score 1):

You can set a single CSS attribute without needing to create an object and certainly without parsing JSON:

```
eleContainer.css(attrName, $(this).val());
```