# How to add a property in existing css class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a css property in a class using JavaScript.

Example

```
<style type="text/css">
.AClass{
   color:#ccc;
   padding:5px;   
}
</style>
```

I want add a property height:500px; in this class using javascript, not on that element which class is AClass. So finally my class should be

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .AClass{
       color:#ccc;
       padding:5px;   
       height:500px;
    }
    </style>
```

But programmatically.

Please Advice me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add CSS with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime