# Change the content of a style class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use css to have animation (using transition) in a div. The content of the div is dynamical (can be 1 line or multiple lines).

I have 2 classes I switch to get the animation effect:

```
.class1{
    max-height: 200px;
}
.class2{
    max-height: 0;
}
```

My problem occurs when the I have only 1 line in the div, so there's "delay" until the 1 line disappears (because the height changes from 200px to 0 while the actual size is only 30px).

I tried to use `element.style.maxHeight = elem.offsetHeight + "px"` to set the `max-height` size but it didn't work so I want to change `max-height` in the class (class1 or class2) to fit the actual size.

How can I change the content of a class (I don't want to have: `"style = max-height: 100px"` in my div)?

Comment: why not create another class with that `max-height` and apply that class instead? (like: `.class3 {max-height: 100px;}`), this is not editing a class, it is applying it.

Comment: You just might want to try to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331169/3880255).

Comment: Use jQuery to either remove class or change style using `.css` method ,, there are various solutions to your problem

Comment: @jackJoe the text can be in multiple lines so I'll need multiple classes, each one for different number of lines... not good idea...

Comment: @Tarekis I saw that thread and it has the same problem: when I delete some of the <li> element and move the cursor from the div, I'll see the delay too...

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/khhvu2qc/) what you need? It's just some basic thing with only the element itself being clickable, but if it is i'll write an answer.

Comment: @Tarekis no, it's not what I meant... How can I change dynamically to have:     .class1{max-height: 100px}

Comment: Guess you need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2076345/3880255) then?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the transition in combination with the `transform`.
Not only because solve your problem, but also because has better performance then change the `height`.
Doesn't make sense changing the height and using CSS, in terms of performance you can use JS, it is the same.

I did an example for you on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n56zr6ra/) because on here seems to do not work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.click-me').on('click', function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('show')) {
      jQuery(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.show {
  transform: translateX(0);
  z-index: 0;
}
.animate {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="click-me animate show">
    <div>one line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still have a problem: when I  move the text up, I can still see it. How can I hide the text (doesn't matter how's the html look, the text shown (I need to hide it).

Comment: my error. If the works, you could accept my answer as correct

Comment: It has problems with visibility which I'm trying to solve. I hope it'll work as I thought and hoped.

Comment: which browser and which cellphone do you have?

Comment: It's not browser, it's the HtmlBox object I'm using. My problem is only on Samsung S3 (and maybe on other old devices, I didn't check it)...