# I need to put a variabile in a <style> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose to have this tag:

```
var variabile_colore="#efdcdc";
```

I need to put a variable in a tag (I think something like this but it not work) :

```
<style>.foot {color: variabile_colore;} </style>
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: use jquery to apply css to any element, instead of such stuff

Comment: Have a look to [You can create style element and insert it into DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2076345/2115381)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a CSS rule / class with jQuery at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/create-a-css-rule-class-with-jquery-at-runtime)

Comment: CSS does not (yet) fully support variables like that; you might want to look into something like SASS to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to apply color property forcefully.

Please try with following.

```
var variabile_colore = "#efdcdc !important";
$('.foot').css('color', variabile_colore);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this you can use DOM objects of javascript by creating an id on style tag :

```
document.getelementbyId('styleid').style.color = "#efdcdc";
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can create dynamic `style` tag using `createElement` and append it in `DOM`

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var sheet = document.createElement('style');
  var color = 'red';
  sheet.innerHTML = "p {color:" + color + "}";
  document.body.appendChild(sheet);
})
```

```css
p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello p tag</p>
<button id='btn'>Change</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery:-

```
$('.foot').css('color', variabile_colore);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to put a variable in a tag (I think something like this but it
>   not work) :

Not sure what exactly it mean
Did you mean to create a `style` tag using js and put declaration in it?

If so then

```
var css= '.foot {color: "#efdcdc";}',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet){
       style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    head.appendChild(style);
```

If style is already present in stylesheet

```
$("#elementId").addClass('foot');
```

If you want to add inline css

```
$('.foot').css('color', variabile_colore);
```

Answer (score 0):

this help you :

```
<body>
       <div class="foot" id="foot">Sample Text</div>
      <script>
          var variabile_colore="#efdcdc";
          var x = document.getElementById("foot");
          x.style.color = variabile_colore;   
       </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because for me it looks like you try to generate a css class from JavaScript. 
Have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076345/2115381).

Here the adaption to your case (not tested):

```
var variabile_colore="#efdcdc";

$("<style type='text/css'> .foot{ color:" +  variabile_colore + 
               "; } </style>" ).appendTo("head");
```