# how can i add class to an element as string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I add a class to my html element as a string

like this:

```
'.step1{transform : translate(10px,10px); transition-duration: 1s;}'
```

I've tried *jquery* `addClass` but it takes only the class name not a string as the whole class.

the problem is i want to generate a class dynamically then remove it using removeClass, if i add it as css it's not possible to remove it easly

Comment: What! You mean the above string in whole is the class?

Comment: you need to directly insert the css properties part as a style attribute.

Comment: How do you mean `add a class to my thml element as a string`? You want to add the _css_ properties _directly_ ?

Comment: the problem is i want to generate a class dynamically then remove it using removeClass

Comment: You need to add remove stylesheet rule(s), e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/create-a-css-rule-class-with-jquery-at-runtime. Then add/remove class to specific element. If you want to change rules, then set e.g an ID to appended style tag and overwrite its content

Comment: Doesn't my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38008870/6338065) provide that? It _adds_ the class and you can _remove_ the class

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. If you hover the second box, the first one moves.

```js
$('.two').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.one').addClass('move');
});

$('.two').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.one').removeClass('move');
});
```

```css
.one, .two {
  background-color:green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.two {
  background-color:red;
}

.move {
  transform: translate(100px, 100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='one'>
  
</div>

<div class='two'>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Should've thought about the _hover_ / _mouseenter/leave_ event instead of stupid buttons :p

Comment: the problem is i want to generate a class dynamically then remove it using removeClass

Comment: @HussanBashiri That is exactly what is happening here, what is unclear exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, This will not add any `class`, it will directly add the styling to the `div`. `addClass()`/`removeClass()` will only use for adding/removing the `class`. The parameter passing inside this will be a `class` name.

```
$('.targetDiv').CSS({"transform" : "translate(10px,10px)", "transition-duration": "1s"});
```

Comment: the problem is i want to generate a class dynamically then remove it using removeClass, if i add it as css its not possible to remove it easly

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Jquery then use `css() function` Know more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

i hope it helps.

```
$(".step1").css({"transform": "translate(10px,10px)", "transition-duration": "1s"});
```

Comment: the problem is i want to generate a class dynamically then remove it using removeClass, if i add it as css its not possible to remove it easly

Comment: you can change this `css` again easily

Answer (score 1):

I've added *two* examples.
One with adding a *class* to the div and placing the style in it.
*or* I've added a Jquery function that *applies* the css to the div *without* adding a class.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/do6w6c04/)

```js
$('#add_class').on('click', function(){
 $("#my_first_div").addClass("step1");
});

$("#add_css").on('click', function(){
$("#my_first_div").css("transform", "translate(10px,10px)");
$("#my_first_div").css("transition-duration", "1s");
});

$("#reset").on('click', function(){
  $("#my_first_div").removeClass("step1");
$("#my_first_div").css("transform", "translate(0px,0px)");
$("#my_first_div").css("transition-duration", "1s");
});
```

```css
#my_first_div {
  color:red;
}
.step1{transform : translate(10px,10px); transition-duration: 1s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id="my_first_div">
my div
</div>

<br /><br /><button id="add_class">
add class
</button>
<button id="add_css">
add css
</button>
<button id="reset">
reset
</button>
```

> explanation: with the *addClass* event a class will be added to the *div* and applies the style that is in the *css* [documentation addclass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)
>
> and [how to remove the class](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)
>
> With the *css* event a *css style* will be applied to the div *without* setting it in the css you can see an example and documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Comment: I think the all point of question is how to write `.step1{transform : translate(10px,10px); transition-duration: 1s;}` dynamically. Maybe OP is  coding for a HTML editor or whatever that needs some reusable/editable CSS rules. But that said, the question is completly unclear imho and your answer is the usual way to add/remove to specific element a class or an inline attribute

Comment: exactly I'm trying to create something like an editor