# jquery append new class to style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

is it possible to append new class with some CSS rules to an element, for example a div, and add this class to **style** section?

For example, when user clicks on a button I want to add new class **'newClass'** with CSS **background-color: red** for my div element, and append

```
.newClass{
background-color: red
}
```

to my `<style>` section. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Simply use `addClass('your_css_class')` method.

Comment: As we don't write up code here at SO, provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe you could show us a [mcve]

Comment: basically you can create a style tag, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/create-a-css-rule-class-with-jquery-at-runtime

Comment: You can append an additional style section to your site at the end of your head using: $("head").append("<style>...</style>");

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CSSStyleSheet.insertRule`

```
 var styleEl = document.createElement('style');

  // Append style element to head
 document.head.appendChild(styleEl);

  // Grab style sheet
 var styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;
 myStyle.insertRule(".myClass { color: red }", 0);
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)

So to do it with your button do:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
   var styleEl = document.createElement('style');
   document.head.appendChild(styleEl);

   var styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;
   myStyle.insertRule(".myClass { color: red }", 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code , this is written whit vanilla javascrit , if you write it with jq it would be better, but it is works

```js
function changeClass(){
  document.getElementById('asdf').className += " newClass";
}
```

```html
<style>
    .newClass {
        background-color: red
    }
</style>
<div id='asdf'>
    aaaa
</div>
<button onclick=changeClass()> click</button>
```