# changing css custom properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i've a JSX module(card.jsx) which is call in another component to create 5 instances of this module(card.jsx).

```
import card.css
...
 <div className='cistern'>
        <div className="shape">
          <div className="wave"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

in my card.css, i have a custom property call *filled*.

```
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    --filled: 20%;
```

in my card.jsx i try to set different value for the css custom variable "*filled*".

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
  var cisternProperty =  document.querySelector( '.wave' )
  cisternProperty.style.setProperty('--filled', showFilledRoundString)
  console.log('show Tank Level', showFilledRoundString)
 }, [])
```

only the first instance use the new value, all other instance used the default "*filled*" value set in the css file.
what's happening? what could be the workaround?
thanks

Comment: `cisternProperty.style.setProperty` will only set that property on the first element due to using `document.querySelector`. It does not apply the property to the css class.

Comment: You may have to overwrite the class by creating a new style element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/create-a-css-rule-class-with-jquery-at-runtime

Comment: You either have to write the property for every instance of cisternProperty (use quesrySelectorAll to get all waves) or set the property not within the wave class but in some ancestor that is common to them all.

Comment: @AHaworth could you elaborate a bit more the querySelectorAll alternative? thanks

Answer (score 3):

To change the CSS property for every instance of an element in the .wave class you can either change the property in some common ancestor element rather than in the .wave elements themselves or you can go through all the .wave elements change their property.

So instead of using querySelector, which gives you only the first element in that class, use querySelectorAll which gives you a collection of all the elements in that class. You can then loop through them setting the CSS variable individually for each one:

```
  var cisternProperties =  document.querySelectorAll( '.wave' );
  cisternProperties.forEach( cisternProperty => {
    cisternProperty.style.setProperty('--filled', showFilledRoundString);
  });
```

Comment: since i'm using map to render each card.jsx instance and showFilledRoundString have a different value for each instance, seem difficult to do these operations within the map call.

Comment: Please be aware that the new property will not apply to any new elements using that class.

Comment: @evolutionxbox how would you do it?

Comment: @Egom, understood (now!) I was just thinkng basic JS.

Comment: @Egom create a new style element and put the modified class definition in that

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

Set the property in a parent element so that it is visible to all child elements

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  var cisternProperty =  document.querySelector( '.shape' )
  cisternProperty.style.setProperty('--filled', showFilledRoundString)
  console.log('show Tank Level', showFilledRoundString)
 }, [])
```

In CSS, do not define the property but use it with a default value. *Here the assumption is that it is used by the element with classname `wave`*

```css
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--filled, 20%);
}
```