# How to add a CSS like styling in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using `Spring MVC` and we are saving some styles directly in our database. There is no CSS file for these styles. Now my problem is that I have styling text like below:

```
.className { 
    background-color: red; color: blue;
} 
.anotherClassName { 
    padding: 15px; margin: 10px;
}
```

I am aware of jQuery `.css` method but its syntax is `css("propertyname","value");`

How can use my styling from jQuery?

Comment: What does your `//styling` look like? Without that - at a minimum - we can't help. Where's your (relevant-only) "*[mcve]*" code?

Comment: @DavidThomas I just updated my question.
Please let me know if there is some thing else confusing

Comment: This "styling text" is just CSS. Insert that in between a `<style></style>` tag in your `<head>` and all elements with those classes should have those styles. No jQuery necessary.

Comment: It's a little unclear, but are you looking for the [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method?   e.g. `$("this").addClass(".anotherClassName")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a CSS rule / class with jQuery at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1212500/1264804)

Comment: @Rick thank you so much for the answer. Your answer did helped me but I think the accepted answer is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this...

```js
const myCssString = `.className { 
    background-color: red; color: blue;
} 
.anotherClassName { 
    padding: 15px; margin: 10px;
}`;

$('<style>', {
  text: myCssString
}).appendTo('head');
```

Comment: Amazing answer sir. Thank you so much for your help.
`Rick's comment` was also working but this answer seems better.
Although I do want to know, where do you get answers of these question.