# jquery change style class attribute value

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have style css cur_font class
I want to change font-family to 'arial' by jquery
and also new font affected on class selectors html,body,h2,h1,div,td

```
    <style>
    .cur_font html,body,h2,h1,div,td { font-family:'tahoma'; }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(".change_font").on("click", function (e) {
            var font='arial';
            $("style.cur_font").css("font-family",font);
        });
    </script>
```

trying to change font-family attribute for class cur_font using jquery

Comment: You would need to alter the stylesheet cssRules. There is no way to select that in JQuery. There are better ways to do this such as multiple rules or CSS variables.

Comment: `$("style.cur_font")` - your style element does not have the class `cur_font`, so this will select nothing. And even if it did, trying to apply a font-family _to_ a `style` element is pointless.

Comment: And `.cur_font html` is quite a pointless selector to begin with - there is not element "above" `html`.

Comment: I know it's bad , what is the best way to change font for all page html , body div, by jquery

Comment: what about $("html,body,div,td").css("font-family",font);

Comment: best solution would be multiple classes and you toggle the class.

Comment: You can create new style rules and add them to the DOM, eg:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076345/2181514   (but separate classes then just set the class is the correct way to go (as noted above multiple times).

Comment: epascarello , what the selector , exmaple please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to toggle a class on the body and apply different styles.

Another approach would be to loop over document.styleSheets and then loop over the cssRules and check to see if the selectorText matches. If it does, modify the rule.

Other option is to use a CSS variable and alter the value of the variable.

```js
document.querySelector(".buttons").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const btn = evt.target.closest("button");
  if (!btn) return;

  const color = btn.dataset.color;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--myVariable', color);
});
```

```css
:root {
  --myVariable: red;
}

div {
  background-color: var(--myVariable);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button data-color="blue">blue</button>
  <button data-color="red">red</button>
  <button data-color="yellow">yellow</button>
</div>
```